# What if I answer a question in a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

If I answered a question in comment, and the person who posted the question said that my comment has solved their problem, should I post an answer in the answers section or is a comment enough?

Comment: Yes. You have to post it as a answer.

Comment: It's not mandatory to post an answer.  If you want to leave an answer in a comment (due to any reason), it is OK. It is however advisable to post an answer if you have time, because answers are more permanent, and can be upvoted/downvoted to indicate usefulness.

Comment: Note: I posted the answer in a comment ^ :D

Comment: I think StackOverflow should consider adding a function to mark a comment as an answer. Not everyone is confident to provide answer from the first look, some of us need extra information and sometimes happens, that while gathering information one may already answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately that feature has been declined [over at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-the-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes. You should post it as an answer. So the OP can accept/mark it as the best answer. This way, it can be useful to other people.

Generally, people don't read comments. They just see if the post has an answer posted, and leave if it doesn't.
Although the question/issue/problem was solved with the comment, it still looks unsolved because the OP can't accept a comment as answer.

Comment: *have to* as an indicator of an action which is strongly recommended but not mandatory is quite acceptable.  *You have to come to my party on Saturday night* vs *You have to die*  No one familiar with SO will mistake the sense in which OP originally wrote *have to*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I disagree. In this sense, especially in a computer-system-about-programming, "have to" is non-optional. "Should" is much clearer here. We are only to "avoid" answering (the) questions in comments. It is not forbidden.

Comment: I think this answer needs a note, that it _doesn't_ mean you should just copy (steal?) somebody else's comment-answer and post it as your own answer (that's just taking credit for what other wizards have done and hijacking the rep.). You should instead (first) stimulate that person to write his/her/their comment as an answer. (I say this, because recently somebody who did such a copy action referred to this answer as an argument to do so)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've had a couple of questions where someone has commented the answer. I wish you could accept comments as containing the answer and/or promote the comment to an answer and then accept it.

My approach is always to ask the commenter to repost the comment as an answer so I can accept it. If they don't respond within a couple of days I'll use "answer your question" and make it clear that the answer is that of the commenter.