# Inaccurate but highly upvoted comments

Tags: discussion, support, comments

This is a rare problem, but an important one to resolve.

There is a [canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python) with a highly upvoted (+285) accepted answer. That answer also has a [highly upvoted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python#comment24458510_16940351) (+50). When I look at answers I *always* look for upvoted comments so I don't miss important insights. I expect other users do exactly the same.

**Why there's a problem**

I happen to disagree with the comment. [Syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) refers to "cleaner syntax" to achieve the same thing. Here, there's a material non-O(1) difference in performance between the two methods.

**Why it matters**

Fast-forward 5 years to [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026406/are-python3-5-tuple-comprehension-really-this-limited), and a couple of answers are influenced by that highly upvoted comment. One user explicitly references it. I would be surprised if this were an isolated instance.

You can look at the comment streams and post revisions to determine the confusion (and effort/time to correct) this causes.

**What I've tried to fix the problem**

1. Ask advice in Python chat room (where I've also shared this Meta). The <strike>one</strike> two users who responded agree with the technical inaccuracy.
2. Add a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python/16940351#comment91009547_16940351) to the canonical answer. With no upvotes, this is hidden by default. The [response](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) from the one who commented yielded no result in terms of rewording / removal.
3. **Edit:** I have now posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053579/list-comprehension-vs-passing-generator-expression-to-list) for clarification.

**If only the comment was in the answer...**

If the problem was content within an Answer, the solution is clear:

- If the answerer is active on SO, ping them and hope they respond. If they don't, downvote and move on. One downvote might not matter in the short-term, but it's what we can do as good SO citizens.
- If the answerer is no longer active on SO, liaise with other members of the community (e.g. Python chat or Meta) and update the incorrect advice if there's a consensus. This has been done before to good effect.

With a comment, these options are not available. Flagging, I believe, is inappropriate as mods are not meant to make judgements on technical accuracy. Is there any better course of action I can take?

Comment: That comment is from a very active user and moderator. I'm pretty sure that if you convinced them of the inaccuracy of the comment, the would act on it. And if they do not want to, and the community voted on the comment, I'm not sure there _should_ be any recourse for the situation beyond the obvious.

Comment: Comments are not answers, nor questions, they are comments. They can get deleted at any time. If the information is relevant to the post in a way that enriches it, include it in the post. That way you can disagree with it.

Comment: @yivi Martijn already replied to jpp's criticism on that comment (see the comments below it). I think he's here to gather support to get it removed anyway, even though the author stands by it, which currently is not really possible with comments. They're pretty much undownvotable and undeletable unless there's a good reason, and we already have a mod standing by that comment.

Comment: @Erik The way I see it the question is about _"what can I do in this situation"_, I reckon if they were trying to gather support to upvote a competing comment or to pressure the comment's author to delete, the question would say so. If the comment author already said they stand by their comment, and the community already expressed their opinion by voting, and the comment is not deletable on other grounds... I guess there is nothing else to do here?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, Exactly, Eric. My point is that there's *no* recourse for comments. The fact it's upvoted doesn't mean "correct". Many initially upvoted *answers* can, over time and on reflection, be downvoted. Here, it's not possible. I mean, technically it's not clarifying the problem or answer. It's adding a fresh, independent view. Can I therefore flag as no longer required?

Comment: Related:  [Please don't write answers in comments](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/please-dont-write-answers-in-comments).

Comment: @jpp in this particular case you probably should write self-answered question "whether both approaches are the same" with answer that shows the difference (which you claim to be probably O(n) vs. O(n^2) based on "non-O(1) difference") and link that Q&A pair from the question... (I have no idea what O(?) for either approach as my Python knowledge stops at "it exists" :) )

Comment: @yivi, Case in point, would you care to [write that in an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) ;).

Comment: I do not believe that comment on itself would work as an answer, but I was hoping it helped someone else if they were to write one. I can try to write a fully fledged answer, though.

Comment: Related: [Are list comprehensions syntactic sugar for `list(generator expression)` in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096351/are-list-comprehensions-syntactic-sugar-for-listgenerator-expression-in-pyth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## We do not have any mechanism beyond votes to correct perceived technical inaccuracies against their author wishes.

Not even for answers, that are far more important than comments.

If someone wrote something you disagree with, you can try to convince them to change it or delete or amend it. But it's up to them to do it. They do not want to? *That's life*. They are not available because they left the site and use Quora exclusively? *That's life*. Fifty other users decided to also disagree with you and vote it up? [*That's life, again*](https://xkcd.com/386/). (Don't get me started on life. Better than the alternative, though).

Your options are the obvious ones:

- Write a counter-point comment. Eventually, some other users will see your comment and vote it up. Once it has a couple of votes it will be visible by default, so there you go.
- Write an answer referencing/quoting that comment and explaining why and how much is wrong (haven't read the linked posts beyond a cursory glance at the comment, so I have no idea if this is pertinent here; trying to address the general case). Again, with time votes will do the work. You may persuade other users, who will comment in turn and maybe you'll end up convincing the original user to delete the offending comment.

Whatever you do, you could also try to bring additional attention to the question/comments/answers highlighting the issue, so other users would also vote what they thing is best (not convinced that meta is the proper place, maybe chat or use external sites link it... it depends on how much effort do you want to invest in this and how important it is for you and how comfortable you are with something like this).

Flagging as *no longer needed* (which you suggest in a comment)? I haven't read the comment and answer, so I do not know if it would be pertinent there. But it seems to me that you want to flag it not because you believe the flag really applies, but simply because you believe the comment is *wrong*. Ask yourself: if you wholeheartedly agreed with the comment, would you really flag it as *nln*?

Otherwise, let's not use flags frivolously. Comments already use up what seems an inordinate amount of moderator time. People complain when comments **are** deleted. People complain when comments are **not** deleted. If the only problem with the comment is of a technical nature, just let it be (flagwise speaking).

<sub>From the little I know of you, and what I read in the question and comments; I think you **already know** all this. But you've asked me to write it up as an answer, so here it is.</sub>

Comment: Dispute `Not even for answers, that are far more important than comments.` We can downvote, that's a mechanism, a very powerful community-driven one :)

Comment: Yup. For comments, you can write your own, and hopefully it'll attract the competing up-votes. Luckily your own comment won't be able to be downvoted either! So fairness all around.

Comment: *Not even for answers* ... Huh? We can (and should) **edit** incorrect answers. We can't edit incorrect comments.

Comment: @wim You can't _"correct"_ an answer against its author's wishes. And if the answer is somehow abandoned, you hopefully take jpp's advice and look for consensus before editing it.

Comment: If it turns out that your edit was against the authors intention, they can edit again or rollback. It's not necessary, and not reliable, to try and second guess their wishes.

Comment: @wim Maybe you didn't read the question completely. But we are talking about cases where the author intent is perfectly clear, and there is disagreement with that intent. Changing the author intent is against the rules, no matter if you think the author is _wrong_.

Comment: Yes. Maybe you could add that context to your answer, too, because it just doesn't read right at the moment.

Comment: There @wim. I added a line which should take care of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You [poked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python#comment91009547_16940351) the original author of that comment, and the original author [disagrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python#comment91032171_16940351), and doesn't want to remove the comment.

The comment isn't flaggable. It's not rude, abusive, unfriendly, spam or "no longer needed". Moderators will most likely decline custom flags, as moderators aren't meant to judge the validity of the site's content.

That pretty much exhausts your options.

Also, don't add a extra answer to the *old* question in order to respond to that comment. Answers are supposed to answer the question.

TL;DR:

You have done everything you can do.

Comment: `Answers are supposed to answer the question.` works *both* ways. See my answer!

Comment: Was that comment supposed to answer the question then? Or was it just a remark / additional information?

Comment: Précisément. But since I also posted an answer, you have the luxury of downvoting it :).

Comment: @jpp: don't assume I voted on your answer. Also, that comment was __on their own answer.__ It was aditional information.

Comment: I didn't presume. But you have the *ability* to vote on my view. Which I think we should *all* respect when disseminating new ideas. Voting is the cornerstone of SO. Getting round it by commenting isn't good.

Comment: Surely, commenting on your own answer is *worse*. I regularly reply to comments in my answers. I then *usually* (and *should*) copy that comment to my answer and delete the comment. If there are lots (3+) unnecessary comments, I then raise a custom flag to get rid of them. Moderators have stated they prefer this, as they have a means of deleting all comments on a post.

Comment: Meh. It's not that bad, imo.

Answer (score -3):

I'm accepting [@yivi's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373272/9209546), but am also going to supply an answer from another perspective.

Answers should be posted as answers. The reasons are laid out clearly in [Please don't write answers in comments](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/please-dont-write-answers-in-comments)<sup>1</sup>, as referenced by @wim. Comments lack quality control as voting is one-sided. A +50 comment can hide -100 downvotes, if downvoting was available for comments. Comments can be used for suggestions / clarification on the problem or answer, but should not be used for disconnected ideas. In the latter case, if the point is important, it should go in an answer.

That said, if someone chooses to post a new idea / answer as a comment, they can go ahead. If it's highly upvoted and incorrect, so be it. There's nothing you can do about it except write your own comment *to clarify the comment* or ask a new question on the issue.

The latter [has already been done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096351/are-list-comprehensions-syntactic-sugar-for-listgenerator-expression-in-pyth).

---

<sup>1</sup> For clarity, this is the primary reasoning, applicable to SO as well as IPS:

> We can't have partial answers here. We just can't. Because
>   poorly-thought-out remarks made by folks who can't or don't want to
>   write a full, good-quality answer can be dangerous. If a
>   comment-answer gets 9 upvotes, then maybe people think "Hey, that's a
>   good idea! 9 other people like it!" But what if there are 30 other
>   people who think it's a terrible idea but can't express it through
>   voting? The comment gets visibility, even though it could be
>   dead-wrong.

Comment: That _"Please don't write answers in comments"_ link is on the interpersonal skills meta. While similar can be said for SO, I don't quite agree with the polarized view in there.

Comment: @Cerbrus This reminds me of [my theory about comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366012/2751851): the more a site leans towards "good subjective", the higher the appropriate strictness of comment moderation is.