# Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance

Tags: support, faq, vote-to-close, close-reasons

**This community-wiki Q&A is a compiled set of guidance for the close reasons used on Stack Overflow.**

It's meant to be a canonical repository and a resource for the community – both for authors of closed questions and for curators judging whether a question should be closed.

###### Authors of questions that are closed

- If you asked a question that was closed, consult this guidance to understand why your question was closed and what you can do about it.

###### Flaggers, Voters and Reviewers

- If you are considering voting to close a question (or flagging it, if you don't have the [privilege to cast close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)), consult this guidance to ensure that you are using the appropriate close reason – and that the question should be closed in the first place.
- If you are a reviewer, consider this guidance on when and what close reasons to use.
- You may also want to link to this post in the comments when you vote to close a question.

---

Each answer to this post explains one of the close reasons on Stack Overflow, including how it is defined, how/when to use it, and what to do if your post is closed for that reason. This resource is community-maintained; if there's something wrong with the guidance provided here, feel free to edit it.

---

### Close reasons – index:

- [Duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417477/)
- A community-specific reason:

  - [Not about programming or software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420218)
  - [Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417480/)
  - [Needs debugging details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417481/)
  - [Not reproducible or was caused by a typo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417482/)
  - [Not written in English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424829)
  - [This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417483/)
  - [Other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417484/) (custom close reasons)
- [Needs details or clarity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417485/)
- [Needs more focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417486/)
- [Opinion-based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417487/)

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Maybe there should be a markdown link in here so people can easily copy/paste it? - `[Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476)`

Comment: @MrMythicalstandswithUkraine click the **share** link under the post to get an URL.

Comment: @bad_coder, well you only get the "raw" (fairly simplified) URL from the `Share` Link, it took me exactly 7 years + 5 months + 3 days to find out the Syntax to use in order to post "clean" Links in a Comment, and I guess I'm probably not the only one "struggling" with that Func, so I find #MrMythical's Comment useful...

Comment: [Can this be added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412863/make-description-of-community-specific-reason-close-reason-more-clear/417360#417360) to the [flag posts privilege wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs: The help pages for each privilege are identical network-wide, so I don't think they can be customized for a specific site. (Even if it were possible, creating a site-specific override of a help center page's text would mean that the site-specific version couldn't be automatically updated anytime the text changed in the network-wide version of that help page.)

Comment: @V2Blast I think it would be great if moderators could edit a section of the privilege pages to include site-specific guidance much like small sections of the tour can be edited. Probably not worth the squeeze, but we can dream, right?

Comment: @IanCampbell: You can always make a request on MSE (if someone else hasn't already done so), and the devs might consider it. (EDIT: I see [you've done so now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377955/335251).) That said, it's worth noting that the top part of [the main Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for each site can be edited by the site mods, and is a good place to include links to relevant resources (as you can see by the other links already there).

Comment: I just made some edits to the `/help/closed-questions` help center article network-wide; since SO already had a site-specific override of that page, I copied my changes over to [SO's version of the article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) – and I added a link to this post while I was at it. :)

Comment: It is interesting to post these as canonical faq reasons when they are actively being reviewed for editing, removal, or refactor. Perhaps this post gets a little ahead of itself. On the other hand, the idea behind creating this centralized area is nice, although, it does make one wonder how it differs from the existing help center and why this wasn't made as an edit there.

Answer (score 20):

### Custom Close Reasons

**How we define custom close reasons**

If a question is closed for this reason, it is because it's off-topic for Stack Overflow in a way not covered by existing closure reasons.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

**Before closing the question for this reason consider the following:**

- Make sure that an existing closure reason doesn't apply. Please use existing closure reasons where possible.
- Ensure the question isn't a good fit for our Q&A format and avoid closure reasons that are about the quality of the question and not the content.

##### Custom Closure Reasons to Avoid:

###### Spam (or Rude/Abusive)

> I’m voting to close this question because it is spam

Don't use a custom closure reason to close the question as spam (or rude / abusive). If the question is spam (or rude / abusive), please [flag it instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

###### Lack of Effort

> I'm voting to close this question because it has no effort to solve the problem

[Lack of effort is not an appropriate closure reason](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388594). If the question is not answerable because it doesn't include enough information to answer, choose "Needs Details or Clarity" instead. If the post asks too many questions or lacks a clear focus, choose "Needs more Focus".

If the question is lacking in effort or research but is understandable and answerable, consider downvoting and / or leaving a comment instead of voting or flagging for closure.

If the question is lacking in research, check whether *doing that research would find an existing (duplicate) question on Stack Overflow*; if there is one, vote to close as a duplicate instead.

###### Resolved without an Answer

> I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

If the question was recently resolved in the comments, consider pinging the user and encourage them to answer the question ([What if I answer a question in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294792)). If the question was resolved in the comments a significant amount of time ago, or the commenter seems disinclined to provide an answer, consider [posting a Community Wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598) which provides [attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) to the individual(s) who resolved the issue.

Consider using the "[Not reproducible or was caused by a typo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417482#417482)" close reason instead if the comment implied the issue was a simple typo or a syntax error.

##### Good Custom Closure Reasons:

###### ✓ Questions for Third-Parties

Some questions aren't answerable by the community of Stack Overflow because they require privileged knowledge about a third party or their processes. These questions aren't on topic anywhere in the Stack Exchange network and should be closed.

| Reason | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| App Store Policy | I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an application store's policy, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information. |
| Customer Support | I'm voting to close this question because it concerns third-party product support (rather than how to write code for that product), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for more information. You should contact the company for support using their service. |
| Product Pricing | I'm voting to close this question because it concerns third-party product pricing and support (rather than how to write code for that product), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for more information. You should contact the company for up-to-date information about pricing. |

---

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- You may be able to reframe your question in a way that is in-scope by reviewing the custom close guidance and any comments from other users. In these cases:

  - Click the “edit” link below your question.
  - Improve your question with your edits.
  - Once your question has been edited and is ready to be reopened, check the box that indicates that this edit resolves the issues with the post and should be considered for reopening.
- Some types of questions need to be asked on other Stack Exchange sites. If that’s the case in your situation, visit that site and ask your question there instead.

  - Copy and paste your question into the “Ask Question” form of the other site.
  - Use the “delete” link below your question to delete it on this site.
- Some questions cannot be answered anywhere on Stack Exchange network. In these cases, you will need to find the appropriate place to ask your question instead.
- If you need specific guidance, consider asking about your question on Meta.

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: Previously, I edited this answer to include talking about using a custom close reason for questions that are not in English. [The current guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673) for non-English questions says it is acceptable to use a custom close reason. But now I see in the history that the change was promptly reverted. What gives?

Answer (score 18):

### Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

*"While similar questions may be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."*

**How we define not reproducible or was caused by a typo**

Some questions are too *localized* to be helpful to anyone other than the author of the post, which is contrary to Stack Overflow's goal of creating a high-quality repository of knowledge. Solutions to typos, syntax errors, or logic issues tightly coupled to *specific* code aren't useful in any other context and are thus closed as "caused by a typo".

Sometimes, the issue can't be reproduced either due to changes making it obsolete, or the problem being device, platform, or project-specific. In these cases, the question is closed for being "not reproducible".

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

##### Before closing the question for this reason, consider the following:

- Is the issue a *common* typo or syntax error? Close as duplicate if there's an existing question, otherwise consider answering.
- If the issue is specific to the author's context only or can't be reproduced by you or other community members, vote (flag) to close for this reason.

---

#### My question was closed.  What should I do now?

- Review feedback (if any) by community members. If the issue was just a typo or a syntax error:

  - Consider if the post can be rewritten to help others with a similar problem. For example, an accidental semicolon in JavaScript:

    > I am getting an "Unexpected token" error in `const a = { a:42; b:24 };`

    can be changed into:

    > What property separators are allowed in an object initializer?
- If the issue can't be reproduced by others, edit the question to provide details on the environment / configuration needed to *consistently* reproduce the problem. If possible, add a [Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) (the snippet [must be runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/11407695)) / playground / code sandbox link where the issue can be reproduced in a controlled environment.

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: As noted in another comment, this current close reason suffers from the "or" problem. Which is it, you can't reproduce the issue, or they simply used `;` instead of `:`? We need more separation in the close reasons, not more explanation of a system that is outdated. These reasons should be self evident.

Comment: @TravisJ why shouldn't we explain to users why their question was closed, using the current close reasons? Just because they may change in 6 to 8 doesn't mean this resource isn't relevant and valuable for those 6 to 8. Don't let perfect be the enemy of good.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Reductio ad absurdum. Your argument that I am somehow asking to not explain close reasons because I am stating we need to refactor the close reasons is trolling at best. I am not even going to address the rest of the nonsense which follows it.

Comment: "Solutions to typos, syntax errors, or logic issues tightly coupled to specific code aren't useful in any other context and are thus closed as "caused by a typo"." Oh, so idiosyncratic logic errors *do* count as typos for this purpose. I don't think this is clear from the term "typo" or from any of the UI framing text.

Comment: *"What property separators are allowed in an object initializer?"* - Is that really a good question? I can just google "javascript object initializer syntax" and find "**comma**-delimited list" in the [first result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). I'm not big into JS though so IDK. Maybe it's just a bad example; in contrast here's a highly-rated question about syntax errors in Python: [I'm getting an IndentationError (or a TabError). How do I fix it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45621722/4518341)

Answer (score 17):

### Needs more focus

*“Your question is too broad or has multiple parts and needs to be distilled into one.”*

Sometimes the scope of a question is too broad because it cannot reasonably or completely be answered in a few paragraphs. Such questions are hard for the community to answer because answers may be too long to easily digest.

This close reason also applies to questions asking *multiple* questions in one. Such posts don't create proper references for people with similar problems, making it difficult for others to find answers. Also, as with too broad questions, answers to such questions tend to be longer and harder to read or write.

**How we define *Needs more focus***

The general definition for such a question is: *a question that is too big for only one question*. Questions of this nature are better off broken down into smaller pieces and asked in separate posts so that our community can focus on key parts individually.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

Before closing the question, *at least one of* the following criteria must be met:

- There are multiple distinct parts to the question
- Any complete answer to the question would have to be very long and excessively detailed to ensure all points are covered (i.e. the question can be answered by an entire book or website)

Note: [Lack of effort is not an appropriate closure reason](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388594). Don't vote to close as *‘Needs more focus’* when the question is narrowly scoped and answerable within our format.

---

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- Narrow the scope — what part of this question is the most important part?

  - Edit your question to reflect a problem that can be addressed in a few paragraphs.
  - Remove bulleted lists of questions — *If you need multiple bullets, it means you're asking multiple questions, and questions on Stack Overflow should ask about one thing, not multiple things.*
- Still have issues that need answers?

  - Search to make sure your extra questions haven’t already been asked; and if not, ask new questions that divide the various those parts of the original post into smaller problems.
- *Remember: one problem — one question!*

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: Are you changing the wording? The actual wording is `This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.` - which I hate and I think can be confusing in the too broad but single question use case. The wording above is better.

Comment: @QHarr it was a deliberate choice, to bring back the old meaning.

Comment: @Braiam Chances we could have that as the actual wording displayed? 0?

Comment: @QHarr if you use twitter, maybe? How many followers you have?

Comment: @QHarr chances are slim but not non-existent. There is a rumor this is going to be followed up by updating the actual notifications and a revamp of community-specific close reasons, but the timeline is uncertain (probably 6 to 8, as usual).

Comment: @Braiam That made me laugh. I have never tweeted and not sure I can only blame my late middling years.

Comment: "Your question is too broad ***or***..." Please let's stop this practice right now when the option is available for us to do so. That "*or*" complicates the entire process here. There is absolutely no reason for us to group close reasons. It makes it harder on everyone. Create two reasons, instead of grouping, and if one of those reasons simply doesn't fit as an actual reason for closure, remove or renovate it.

Comment: Consequently, it should be immediately obvious that "your question is too broad" is absurd without proper explanation, and in those reasons explaining why the question is too broad, you will identify the set of close reasons we actually need.

Answer (score 13):

### Needs debugging details

*“The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.”*

**How we define Needs debugging details**

If a question is closed for this reason, it is because there is not enough information in the question itself to reproduce the described behavior or issue.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

Before closing the question for this reason:

- The question **must** primarily be about **debugging code** or determining why a specific behavior is happening; and
- The question must be missing sufficient information/code to reproduce the described behavior; or
- The question is not self-contained: the code is in an inaccessible format like an image or is hosted in an offsite repository; or
- The question contains so much extraneous code that it is a pain to isolate and debug the problem.

---

#### My question was closed.  What should I do now?

- Edit your question - to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

  - Minimal

    - Minimal doesn't necessarily mean short. Focus on ensuring there is exactly enough code or information to reproduce this issue, and remove the things that are not directly relevant to this issue ([What is the largest number of lines one should post for code examples or data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415947))
    - If you have no idea what part of the program is causing the problem, start by debugging your program to isolate just the part causing the issue
  - Complete

    - Ensure the question is self-contained

      - If your code is hosted offsite, move the relevant sections into your question
      - If you have images of code or error messages, copy them into your question as text instead ([Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557))
  - Reproducible

    - For code-related questions, try copying your code into a clean work space to ensure it will reproduce the issue
    - Include any relevant version information
    - For data processing or transformation questions, provide sample input/sample data
- Read any comments - often users will ask for specific information needed to reproduce the issue
- Describe - the behavior you are seeing
- Explain - how that actual behavior differs from what you expected
- Once your question has been edited and is ready to be reopened, check the box that indicates that this edit resolves the issues with the post and should be considered for reopening

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: This advice is problematic. SO is not a debugging site. It's a QA site. The demand for a MRE is actually a trick to get the OP to debug their code. But this advice gives the wrong impression.

Comment: @Raedwald But isn't giving the wrong impression still tricking the user into debugging the code?  And if this is supposed to be achieving the approach by trickery, wouldn't a "wrong impression" not necessarily be a negative, since it still does that? Not that I personally believe "trickery" is a great approach, just musing upon the logic here.

Comment: What would be helpful is how to distinguish this close reason from ‘Needs details or clarity’.

Comment: @user3840170 good idea, although I am not sure I myself understand what the difference between them is. They kind of do mean the same thing with only one exception that the standard close reason has wider application as questions do not  have to be about debugging code to be closed against it.

Comment: I seem to recall ‘Needs details or clarity’ as originally being something like ‘Too vague to be answerable’, but Stack Exchange watered it down to avoid offending askers’ sensibilities or something. Which ironically, made the close reason too vague to be actionable in many cases.

Comment: @user3840170 IRRC, it [was called](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/) "not a real question". Not the best wording, admittedly, but the rework did not help much either.

Comment: This close reason fails in so many regards. It is essentially used as a more wordy version of "cannot reproduce". If it takes an essay to explain, it is probably because it doesn't actually make sense to use. Many users like to use this close reason when they know something should be closed, but don't have a good option to properly explain why, so they go with the massive hurdle of requiring a mre and arm waive about lacking details. Most of the questions do need to be closed, but incorrectly using this leads to the broken window fallacy and to legit questions being closed.

Comment: What about questions that do not need code clarify it? For example general syntax errors or clarifications on how to approach errors like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090019/how-to-approach-perl-error-unterminated-operator-at ... adding sample code will only narrow the usefulness and clarity of the question in my opinion... my question was closed, but maybe this is only a case where someone is using this close reason inappropriately.

Comment: @MarianoPaniga we have a process for getting questions that are closed incorrectly reopened - the review just finished, and I see your question is reopened as reviewers agreed it should be. This close reason is, indeed, *not* to be used for questions that do not need code, don't worry - see the first bullet point of the guidance: "The question must primarily be about debugging code"

Comment: @Raedwald it's a trick to get users to *try to* debug the code. In many optimistic cases, this process results in "I have a few lines of code like so, and I expect the output to be X because of <reasoning>, but it is Y instead. I can see the exact point in the debugger where the computed value doesn't match my expectation, but why is this result computed?"

Comment: While code isn't necessary to understand the Perl question, I feel like some examples would be helpful for *making it look like the right question* for people who find it with a search engine. Although in this particular case, it might also increase the risk of people deciding to close it as caused by a typo.

Comment: If it is possible to create an MRE and it would improve the question and OP ignores requests to do so then I vote to close.  Yet, this is often a moot point as questions that require significant  work to reproduce often go unanswered anyway.

Answer (score 11):

### Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

**How we define *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more***

Recommendation questions are posts that request opinion-based recommendations for off-site resources (a pointer/link to somewhere outside of Stack Overflow) to solve the problem. The question asks for *what* to use or read, rather than *how* to do something.

We don't allow these types of questions because they have the potential to attract spam answers promoting products, services, websites, and more. Additionally, chances are, even the best recommendations today [will be obsolete within a year](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), meaning the question doesn't serve as a good long-term reference for other users.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

##### Before closing the question for this reason, consider the following:

Is the question asking for a recommendation for an off-site resource — except for requests for an **official** source ([When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479))? If yes, vote to close for this reason.

---

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- Some questions may be suited for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If your question is on-topic on either of these sites, use the "Delete" button under your post on Stack Overflow and repost your request on the appropriate site. **Be sure to ensure your question abides by the requirements of the target site.**
- If you were looking for *how* to do a specific task, edit your question outlining what specific task you were looking to accomplish and be sure to check the box so that it can be reviewed for reopening.
- If you were looking for an official source, edit your question making it clear that you were looking for a canonical or official resource and not asking for general recommendations.

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: What should we do when the question doesn't ask about a library, but simply asks "how do I do X?" and the only reasonable answer is "it is not feasible to write the code yourself, but library Y is the industry standard for solving these sorts of problems, and in this case you would just use `Y.foo()`"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it might be Too Broad in some cases. But the form of answer you suggest seems fine and on topic - it's possible that the question is as well. Answering with a suggestion of using a library is fine normally. *Asking* for a library has a tendency to devolve into poorly maintained Q&A.

Answer (score 11):

### Needs details or clarity

*“As currently written, the question lacks enough detail or clarity to be answered.”*

Being specific about relevant details, while omitting irrelevant details, is the best way to get the answers you seek.

**How we define questions that need details or clarity**

If a question is closed for this reason, it is because what is being asked lacks sufficient information necessary to effectively answer the question. It is important for those answering to have as much relevant information as possible. “An answer is only as good as the question being asked,” stands true for this definition. If it is unclear what is being asked, answering the question will be impossible.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

Before closing the question, *at least one of* the following criteria must be met:

- The question is unanswerable without further details.
- Answering would require many branching solutions based on guessing what the question is asking.
- There isn't a sufficient amount of information to understand what is being asked or the intent of the question.

This close reason is only actionable to the person who asked the question when it is accompanied by a comment that says what needs to be clarified. When using this close reason, please consider leaving a comment asking for the specific details that would clarify the question for you.

Example reasons that a question could need details or clarity:

Lacking Clarity:

- Incomprehensible grammar or spelling that can’t be corrected with community edits
- Doesn’t ask a question

Needs Details:

- Needs to have terms defined
- Missing crucial information (*e.g.* programming language)
- Discrepancies in explanation and expected behavior

---

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- Read any comments; often users will ask for specific information needed to understand what is being asked.
- For questions with code, edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clearly demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish.
- Try to make your explanation as concise as possible.
- If your question shows expected output, be sure to include an explanation of *why* that output is correct and *ensure* that the explanation and the expected output match.
- Click the “edit” link below your question.
- Improve your question with your edits.
- Once your question has been edited and is ready to be reopened, check the box that indicates that this edit resolves the issues with the post and should be considered for reopening.

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: Not sure if we are "allowed" to post Comments, remove when "not needed anymore"... // I find "*Missing crucial information (e.g. programming language)*" a bit "exaggerated" as a Reason to close a Qt, shouldn't first a Comment be posted asking for that Info, and maybe only 24h later if the @OP didn't react/follow up, then OK, go to 'Close'...? // More "realistic" than "forgetting" to mention their Prog Language, would be to mention the Version they (the Asker) are using, as for some Tags/Prog Languages, not all Commands are implemented/supported or behave the same in all Versions/Environments.

Comment: @chivracq last time I checked, the guidance on closing was: [as soon as possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close). The onus is on the question author to have all the necessary information at the time of posting, not after.

Comment: As for the comments - allowed *and* encouraged - the goal is to get as much wider community feedback as possible!

Comment: @Oleg, well, OK, but that voids a bit the "Purpose" of Comments to "Ask for Clarification (or missing Info)"... // And what about "*Missing Prog Language*", have you ever seen a Qt where the Prog Language is not mentioned...? When selecting Tags, the first Tag Askers will select is the Prog Lang related to their Qt, or they are "so stupid", they should stay away from Programming, and from a Computer at all also maybe...

Comment: @chivracq not at all - the comments asking for clarifications are still expected, the only difference is that it is expected for the OP to add missing details and then initiate the reopen procedure - that's *always* been the way how closure works. As for the missing language - not really, but it oftentimes vital information about the *dialect* is missing. Many questions related to SQL and regular expressions are guilty of that. The example is not set in stone, maybe it should be replaced with a more common situation.

Comment: Yeah OK, but my "main Point" is about "*Missing crucial Info" + "*Prog Language*"  as (only) Example... When referred to this FAQ with their Qt being closed for "Missing crucial Info", the Asker(s) will think "Euh..., well, I did mention the Prog Language, so it doesn't apply to me, what's the Problem...!?"..., and that will give some "Food" for endless Discussions in Comments in the Qt itself, and probably on Meta also...

Comment: The purpose of closing questions is to prevent answering them on the current state of the question. If the current state of the question does not allow for good answers, this clearly should happen as quickly as possible. That's why closure is designed to be reversible.

Comment: **ALWAYS edit the question** and **NEVER post a new one.** If you post a new one you are vulnerable to downvotes for deleting a question and or for posting a duplicate question. I tried posting a new one and ended up with 4 downvotes in the process.

Answer (score 11):

### Not about programming or software development

*"Use this close reason if the question is not about [a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Do not use this close reason for questions that are on-topic for Stack Overflow, even if they would also be on-topic on [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Questions about Stack Overflow itself should be migrated to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) instead."*

**How we define not about programming or software development**

Questions on Stack Overflow must be about either a specific programming problem, an algorithm, or a software tool *primarily* used by programmers. These topics constitute *programming context*. General computing, networking (unrelated to specific programming problems), optimization of *working* code, and general-purpose tools (the list is not exhaustive) do not.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

##### Before closing the question for this reason, consider the following:

- Is the question on-topic on Stack Overflow? Being on-topic on another site of the network doesn't *automatically* make it off-topic here.
- Is it asked in the programming *context?* (Merely being an *activity that programmers perform* doesn't constitute context.)
- Is it asking about Stack Overflow itself? It belongs on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) — close as "[this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417483)" instead.

---

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- Determine if the question can be edited to be on topic.

  - Clarify any programming context that is not immediately apparent in the initial revision.
- Determine if there is [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) where the question *may* be on-topic.

  - Make sure to read their Help Center to confirm to the best of your ability that it will be acceptable on the target site. If you do decide to repost on a different Stack Exchange site, make sure to delete your question on Stack Overflow, [as posting the same questions on multiple sites (cross-posting) is generally not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069).

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Answer (score 10):

### Opinion-based

*“This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.”*

Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or objective solutions.

**How we define *Opinion-based***

Stack Overflow is an objective *question-and-answer* site, not a discussion forum, and while discussions focusing on diverse opinions are great, they don't fit our format well. We rely on factual information so we can properly curate our library of knowledge.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

Before closing the question, *at least one of* the following criteria must be met:

- The question’s primary goal is to solicit opinions
- Answers are based primarily on opinion rather than factual information

---

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- If the intent of the question was to solicit opinions, it is not a good fit for our format. However, there may be [another site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) on the Stack Exchange network which can answer the question; be sure to check their "How to Ask" and "On Topic" pages in their Help Center first.
- If you are looking for a fact-based answer to a practical programming problem, and you believe that your question isn't primarily based on opinions or can be edited so it is not:

  - Remove phrases such as “What is the best?”, “Which is better?”, or “What do you think?”
  - Clarify with a specific goal; for example: *"What's the best way to do X?"* would be better as *"How can I improve the runtime of X with regard to Y?"*

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: I feel like this entry should include some kind of reference to https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: IMO, "Answer" has a technical meaning on Stack Overflow - it refers specifically to an attempt to answer the question (whether or not successful, but intended as such), written in the answer section *and not as a comment or edit*. That arguably justifies the capitalization.

Answer (score 9):

### Duplicate Questions

*“This question has already been asked, and answered.”*

If the ‘fundamental goal’ is to create a roadmap to the canonical answer, we must first make sure that duplicates are actually that: questions that have been asked and answered before on Stack Overflow.

**How we define Duplicate Questions**

Duplicate questions are defined as questions that have already been answered on this site. All closures should follow an apples-to-apples comparison. In other words, if the question matches exactly to one that has been previously asked, or if the question is closely related and there is an answer that would serve both questions, that question should be marked as a **[Duplicate]** and linked to the canonical.

An unanswered question may also be marked as duplicate if an existing Q&A can answer the question.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

Before closing the question, *at least one of* the following criteria must be met:

- The question has been asked before.
- The duplicate target has at least one answer that is accepted or has a score of 1 or higher.

For more in-depth guidance, see  [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844)

---

#### My question was closed as [Duplicate]. What should I do now?

- Review all the answers on the duplicate target or targets. Do they solve your problem?

  - **Yes, the duplicate(s) solve my problem**

    You don't need to do anything. The question now serves as a signpost to future readers with the same problem.
  - **No, the duplicate(s) do *not* solve my problem**

    If this is the case, your goal should become *differentiating* your question from the marked duplicate so that it can be reopened and answered.

  Now the burden has shifted from "Why are these questions considered duplicates?" to "How can I prove that these questions are *not* duplicates?", and it's *your* job to make the distinction clear.
- Try editing your question.

  - *It won’t help to add comments to your question or to ask the same question a second time. The ONLY way to get your question answered is to edit it with more details and get it reopened.*

    - *Reposting your question will likely result in a duplicate closure against your previous question.*
  - Click the “edit” link below your question.
  - Make sure that the title of your question is substantially different from the title of the marked duplicate.
  - Describe your problem better, including an explanation of how your problem differs from the marked duplicate.
  - Explain why the answers to the linked duplicate do not solve your problem.
  - Make sure your code matches the question that is being asked.
  - Make sure the question is properly tagged.
- *Avoid* edits that:

  - *Call out specific users for closing the question.*

    - Those users will not be notified and it is generally unproductive as it takes away focus from the actual question.
- Check the "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening" checkbox and save your edit. This causes your question to enter the reopen queue where it will be reviewed.
- The review process can take between several hours and days. You may be able to speed up the process by inviting specific people to review your question for reopening.

  - You can ping anybody that commented on your question by mentioning their name in the comments with an @ symbol in front of it. See [How do @-mentions work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/786798) for an in-depth explanation.

    *Ex: “@Jeff I updated the question because it shouldn’t be marked as a duplicate. Can you take a look at it?”*

    If your question was closed by a single person, you can also ping that person, however, if your question was closed by a group of people, ping doesn’t work for those individuals.

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: Shouldn't this here at least also mention the official guidance which is: "If this question doesn't resolve your question, ask a new one." to be consistent with it? Or am I just not seeing it? Or is the official guidance considered inaccurate and editing of a closed question is always preferred?

Comment: @Trilarion yes, that guidance is inaccurate. Editing is preferred, to the extent that it would not invalidate answers.

Comment: I feel like this guide narrowly skirts the line whether *questions* or *answers* should be similar. Some parts lean heavily towards the former (e.g. "question matches exactly to one that has been previously asked") or the latter (e.g. "there is an answer that would serve both questions"). Having the latter IMO includes the former, but I can see people weighing this differently. Clearly committing to only one could avoid people cherry picking whatever definition suits their fancy.

Comment: I am with @Braiam here. The current wording suggests that two different questions can be marked as duplicates, if one question contains a quality answer that answers both questions. For example (1) *"How to remove duplicates from a List?`"* and (2) *"Why my list is corrupted after calling List.RemoveAll?"*. If I write [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71365768/11178549) to (1) that accidentally also addresses the (2), then the (2) should be marked as a duplicate of (1). That's wrong. It's apples and oranges. These two are different questions.

Answer (score 9):

### This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

On Stack Overflow, it is important to know what kind of questions can be asked and what subjects are in scope. Our platform is for anyone who codes and so the definition of “on-topic” for Stack Overflow are questions that usually include *some* code and encompass:

- a specific, objective programming problem or
- a software algorithm or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

**How we define questions that are eligible for migrations**

- This question is out of scope for Stack Overflow but is a good question and appears to be on-topic on another site of the network.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

Please check out our community FAQ post ["What is migration and how does it work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) for in-depth info and workflow of migrations of questions to other sites in our network.

##### Before closing the question for this reason, consider the following:

Ensure it is not a practical, answerable programming problem, or question unique to software development, and the following criterion is met:

- The question is out of scope on SO, but a variation of the question would be well received on another site

  - Available site migrations are:

    [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

    [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

    [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

    [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

    [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - Please review those sites on-topic Help Pages (linked above) to find what kind of questions are appropriate for those sites.
  - Please also search the destination site to see if the same question is not already asked and answered there: if it is, vote to close the question for a different reason and leave a comment with the existing question. (If it doesn't answer their question, the author can post a new question there.)

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- If the migration completes successfully, the post will be open on the destination site with a notice that it was migrated. At this point, you don't have to do anything on the origin site, but you should tend to your question on the destination site:

  - Address feedback by community members on the destination site. If the post is closed or deleted *for any reason* (unless it's closed as a *duplicate* or deleted while closed as such) on the destination site, the migration will be *rejected* and then *reversed*.
  - Double-check and edit the *tags* on the question to help its discoverability. Only tags from the origin site that exist on the destination site will be preserved. If none exist, the migration will be blocked and the question will simply be closed as off-topic (unless you're a moderator, in which case the post will have the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag).

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

Comment: Would it be useful for the "Before closing the question for this reason, consider the following" paragraph to explain what to do when there is a matching Stack Exchange site that isn't listed? This gets regularly  asked on meta and closed as a dupe of either [Can we have more options in the Closing > Off-Topic > Migration](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253869) or [Flagging migration should include more options](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251652).

Comment: Yes. Migrations definitions were difficult for our team to properly define or give guidance to, and we acknowledged we would be leaning heavily on the community for this. So please, add and edit were you deem applicable. :)

Comment: Why do we only have a list of "SE" sites for migration? And why is it so small? Why cant we select another site just for OP's education (not migration)?

Comment: @mxmissile see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/11407695) for an explanation as to why - migrations are a problematic topic, it's unlikely that we will ever get the full list of network sites.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I realize the issues with migration. However, let me close it and select a site anyway, informing (educating) the OP which site it belongs on, forget about migration.

Comment: I mean, what if your advice is wrong? At least with a comment, it can be easily deleted.

Comment: Let's settle this:  comments to recommend someone go to another site - always have been unreliable.  Flagging for moderator attention - preferable.  Thoughts?  Reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254415/1079354

Comment: Flags for moderator attention requesting migration of other people's questions are difficult to evaluate and likely to be declined if neither the moderator nor the requester is an experienced user of the target site.

Comment: Okay, that's exactly what I wanted to ask about @RyanM.  So what's the resolution - just close and no comment?  (Something I'd prefer)

Comment: @mxmissile I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry! I only meant to indicate that the migration process is quite a mess, and the list is unlikely to be expanded due to many communities being against us migrating questions to them (Code Review folks, for example, are very pissed off by migrations from SO). The whole process likely needs to be reworked before the list can become open (one possible idea - restrict the list to sites where the close voter / flagger has more than 101 rep [to account for assoc bonus]).

Answer (score 7):

### Not written in English

*"Use this close reason if the question is not [written in English](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). Do not use this close reason for questions that are primarily written in English but happen to contain non-English variable names, error messages, or other short excerpts."*

**How we define not written in English**

A post is considered not written in English if it primarily consists of text in a language other than English or contains text or images **required** for correct understanding of the post that primarily consist of non-English content.

**Do not attempt to translate such posts** — the author needs to be able to communicate with those who answer and comment on the post, so you are only doing them a disservice if they cannot. Only the author of the post should translate it.

---

#### How to use this reason to close questions

Before closing the question for this reason, consider the following:

- Questions containing non-English text or images that do not have to be in English to understand the post should not be closed with this reason. Examples of complementary information include:

  - error messages (unless required to establish the problem);
  - variable names or string literals in code;
  - user interface screenshots.
- If the post contains superfluous non-English content (such as greetings, salutations, and taglines) **and** your language proficiency is high enough to determine that with certainty, edit it out instead.

---

#### My question was closed. What should I do now?

- If you can, translate the post via means available to you. Do note that all answers and comments on your question will be in English, so make sure you are prepared for that.
- If you cannot translate the post, consider deleting it here and reposting on one of the localized versions of Stack Overflow, provided your language is in the list:

  - [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) (Stack Overflow em Português)
  - [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) (Stack Overflow на русском)
  - [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (Stack Overflow en español)
  - [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (スタック・オーバーフロー)

---

[Return to the index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)