# Is "I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't show any attempt or work" a valid custom close reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

It was pointed out to me that *"I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't show any effort"* isn't a valid custom close reason. This was discussed in the comment section of [How to sort object entries by key order from another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898291/how-to-sort-object-entries-by-key-order-from-another-array?noredirect=1#comment127050009_71898291)

But according to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): *"Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"* and *"Questions that need improvement may be closed until someone fixes them."* the lack of any attempt or work is a close reason.

Is *"I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't show any attempt or work"* a valid custom close reason? If it's not a close reason, shouldn't the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) be updated to avoid confusion?

In meta I can find multiple similar questions with many different and contradicting answers. Someone could pick one answer supporting their point and I could pick a different answer supporting my point. Aren't the clear guidelines in the tour and the help center above the discussions in meta containing different opinions?

Comment: @Ivar Not really, because it doesn't describe the importance of the [tour] and if it should be corrected. And the link contains opinions of individuals, not global guidelines. And even in this one link the opinions are contradicting. I can find answers supporting my point.

Comment: Shog at the time of writing was still a CM IIRC. So I'd say it has some weight. But regardless, the question on whether "no effort" is a valid close reason has been discussed plenty of times before. The outcome is usually the same.

Comment: @Ivar The second answer contains _"In general, if a question really doesn't show any effort and is just soliciting opinions or guidance, that's likely too broad. [...] If an asker wants to make it clear that they have code and that they have a problem, then the problem needs to be self-contained. If it isn't, then you can close it for that applicable reason."_

Comment: The short answer is "No, you should not vote to close due to lack of effort or attempt."  The only effort we require is the effort to write a clear, focused problem that's not a duplicate.  And if it's a duplicate, you need to close it as a duplicate, not due to lack of effort.

Comment: And personally I'd say, keep it in the tour. It still can shield you from some down votes and might make an otherwise unclear question more clear.

Comment: @RyanM Why isn't the tour updated in that case? Isn't it contradicting? The tour clearly states that a question without any attempt or work may be closed.

Comment: Kind of, yeah.  I'd be interested in hearing better phrasing suggestions.

Comment: In one duplicate I see _Or "unclear where exactly you are stuck"_ In that case, "no effort" is not an official close reason but questions showing no effort can be closed with _"Needs details or clarity"_

Comment: If they are _unclear_ due to lack of effort, yes, they can be closed as *Needs details or clarity*.  However, if they're clear but simply lack problem-solving effort, they cannot.

Comment: It's not a contradiction to say that it may be closed because that only means that it *might* be closed. The tour is not promising that all questions without an attempt will be closed.

Comment: @BSMP But I understand it as I'm free to vote to close because of this reasons. Isn't that at least one possible, grammatically correct interpretation of this two sentences?

Comment: That interpretation doesn't make sense in context. 1) The tour is for brand new users who wouldn't have close vote privileges (at most they'd have 101 rep from the association bonus). 2) That section is clearly talking about asking questions, not moderating them. It's telling someone who's thinking about asking a question that it might get closed. It's not telling a brand new user that they're free to vote to close.

Comment: @BSMP The second point is correct. It's about asking a question and not closing one. But I'm not a brand new user and I'm still reading the tour to check which questions can be asked and which can't. At least to me it's confusing that the tour states that these questions may be closed but some users say something contradicting. And even in meta you can find different opinions. Who are the official users with official answers?

Comment: The tour doesn't set out close-vote reasons. It provides guidelines on how to ask a good, high-quality question. The close-vote reasons are documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, there is a list of close vote reasons, but it doesn't contain valid reasons for a custom close vote. The tour lists questions without attempt or work as bad that may be closed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions describes a custom close vote reason that can be used when other reasons don't fit. Some user say, it's okay to close questions that don't show work. You have to admit, that's confusing.

Comment: For guidance on custom reasons, please see the new guidance we've just released [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417484/208273).

Comment: @RyanM It's not trivial to find. It could be more prominent, e.g. in the help center. But it answers my question.

Comment: I agree. It's quite new; hopefully we'll be able to get it linked from more places in the future.

Comment: A real easy way to find out if something is closable: Is it answerable and is it on-topic? If yes - do *not* close it (except if it's a duplicate). If no - then you can vote to close it. Anything else is irrelevant. SO does not have a "code tax". You don't have to pay "one code" to get "one answer". If it's unclear *because* there is no code provided, then vote "Needs details or clarity" or "Lacks debugging details". Some times "Needs more focus" might also be appropriate. If the question is clear without code [then the choose this from the close dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9F5l.png)

Comment: Close it for lack of focus , that would be true and is valid

Comment: So, I'm feeling kind of stunned by this as I don't think it's the way that SO generally works.  Questions just asking us to write code for them that show no effort to solve it themselves, but do clearly show the problem to be solved are just fine?  A classic question (which we seem many times a week) is I have this input data structure and I want to change it to this output data structure.  Throw in a few special circumstances that make it so there's no duplicate that really illustrates how to write this code.  So, that's just fine and dandy on SO?

Comment: @jfriend00 Examples of this might be helpful. Generally, we try to encourage questions that could conceivably be *applicable to someone else in the future*.  **Requiring problem-solving effort in the question is often counterproductive** to this goal.  For example, we have a few questions that have turned into a canonical, highly voted question, where the top answer basically says "you made a typo here, here's the correct code," - focusing on the specific incorrect attempt. The question would have been so much better without the attempt, allowing answerers to suggest the best way to do it.

Comment: @RyanM - That's a bit hard to search for, but maybe I could accumulate ones I see over the next week.  Here's [one closed today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906056/please-some1-should-help-explain-to-me-in-detail-what-each-line-of-the-javascrip) that isn't a great example for the stated reason of "needs details", but the question actually seems very clear to me as "please explain each line of Javascript" in this page.

Comment: As a side note, I was looking for examples of this by searching recent closed questions.  Wow, what a lot of junk reasons for closing questions.  This community is horrible at closing questions for (needs details or clarity) that are not difficult to understand and answer and no duplicate has been shown.  I don't have to look very long and they are easy to find.  I also see lots of questions being marked a duplicate where the duplicate does not contain what would be considered a good or modern answer.  In all these cases, I don't see how closing the question is helping the OP or helping SO.

Comment: [cont'd].  No wonder SO has a crummy reputation with people new to the site when so many questions get closed for bogus reasons.  It feels like "cleaning up the site of un-clever questions" is given a much higher priority than actually helping people who post.

Comment: I think this is also a good exmple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71911078/write-a-function-shufflearrthat-takes-input-an-array-of-numbers-and-returns-an

The "question"/task is absolutely clear and not really too broad. Maybe there is a duplicate, but maybe not. It already has two close votes. Why? According to the comments in this question(_"Is it answerable and is it on-topic? If yes - do not close it (except if it's a duplicate)"_),  it's a valid (but bad) question. It can be answered, it's a programming question, and I'm able to answer it. I can downvote, but not vote to close.

Comment: On the other side, doesn't this close reason contain zero-effort questions: _"Needs debugging details

The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**."_ Questions without any code could be closed with _"Needs debugging details"_

Comment: @jabaa Only *debugging* questions need debugging details. The question is on-topic, albeit not exactly well asked; I've seen pretty much the same question for Python.

Comment: FWIW, it certainly doesn't help that the question *as presented* is just a dump of an exercise description. It lacks an actual question, which is certainly a lack of a significant detail. Whether one wants to be that literal, well...

Comment: *"But I'm not a brand new user..."* This is my point: the tour wasn't written for experienced users looking for detailed close vote guidance. That's not what it's for. It's like you're looking at the Quick Start guide for an electronic device for instructions for how to mod it.

Comment: You can flip this question on its back. When is it a good idea to cast a custom close vote? In my experience: for corner cases that are definitely bad but won't happen too often. "Not enough effort" is so common that it would be a close reason that is just in the list. But it isn't. Hint hint.

Comment: Why is this question closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71925875/how-can-i-restrict-a-counter-from-going-negative-in-javascript/71925944?noredirect=1#comment127096481_71925944 How is it lacking focus? The focus is very clear on one single problem, that can be solved in one single line. Obviously, this question was closed because of zero-effort, but lacking focus was used as the close reason.

Comment: @jabaa "please explain the logic along with the syntax involved" seems like a huge scope. The OP apparently doesn't even seem to know how to do a basic value check (else the question wouldn't be there), so a proper answer would have to dig into the absolute basics and explain things from the ground up. That's far, far more than "one single line".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Are you serious? The logic to keep the result of a decrement function non-negative is a huge scope? Saying, "if the result is negative, set it to 0" is to much or not answering the question? What more basics do you need to write a correct answer?

Comment: @jabaa The problem is to *explain the entire logic and syntax* when the OP apparently doesn't know the most basic language elements. Saying "if the result is negative, set it to 0" *doesn't do that*, so it is pretty irrelevant that this would be a simple answer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The OP already knows and uses the assignment operator and knows how to define and use functions. I don't need anything in my answer that the OP doesn't already use. It's enough to call one function `Math.max` and assign the result to `i`. The OP already knows how to do this. I don't have to explain anything new.

Comment: @jabaa And why exactly do you assume they understood everything they used? It's not exactly uncommon for people to work with cargo cult code and use [so] to incrementally crawl along. If they already knew everything they are asking for, they wouldn't be asking about it, would they?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So you're assuming, that the OP doesn't understand the code in their own question, because it's a basic problem for you, and that's a correct close reason? But closing because of zero-effort is not correct? So, according to this, most basic questions can be closed, because we can assume, that we would have to explain the whole language basics? The OP asked a clear, focused and answerable question and you would close because of some assumptions. Couldn't you use this close reason with this unsubstantiated assumptions for almost all questions?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Isn't the goal of this platform to help future users with similar problems? Isn't the title, the description and the code in the question clear and focused enough, to 1) answer the question and 2) help future users with a similar problem? Doesn't the answer help future users?

Comment: @jabaa The question was *explicitly* asking to "please explain the logic along with the syntax involved". You are the one assuming that this can be skipped.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The logic is that `Math.max(i - 1, 0)` replaces the negative value with a 0. I don't understand, why this would be too complex to answer. I didn't skip it. It's just so simple. I daily see much more complex questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jabaa And because it is so simple and not at all complex, they still needed you to change their entire code for them? Yes, your answer is short and focused *but it doesn't seem to satisfy their question*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The goal of Stack Overflow is not to help one individual. It's to collect all possible specific technical problems and solutions to help future users with the same problem. The question is clear, focused and answerable. No reason to close. It was already reopened, but this behavior proves how confusing the close reasons are. People use different reasons to close zero-effort questions.

Comment: Alone in this comment section I can see multiple users with very high reputation and many years of experience on Stack Overflow with very different opinions. How could some tell me, there is a consence or a guideline how to handle, if even these users don't agree?

Comment: @jabaa although I am not casting doubt on the competency of users involved, I have to note that neither metric is an indicator of expertise on site governance. We have plenty of high-rep 10+ years users who do not have the slightest clue about how the network works. Additionally, closure always judgment calls, so there is bound to be at least *some* disagreement - that does not mean there is no community consensus.

Comment: @jabaa I fully agree with reopening the *edited* question. Please do not overinterpret what can be said in a comment thread that has trailed off so far from where it started.

Comment: @jabaa - But, the fuel that drives creating a long term, useful repository of Q/A is that people come here with questions and they get helped.  If that breaks, the whole tower falls down and SO becomes a historical reference without a lot of new participants.  So, the site needs to never swing so far in favor of the value of the long term repository.  The fuel for growth is new users asking new (to them) questions.  Nothing should break that.  There's definitely a shift happening in that direction now.  Curating can't become more important than actually helping people solve their problems.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that's the reason I answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71925875/how-can-i-restrict-a-counter-from-going-negative-in-javascript/71925944?noredirect=1#comment127096481_71925944 and voted to reopen. I just want to understand the correct behavior and some users think, this question should be closed and even tried to explain the close reasons to me. TBH I don't get it, but I'll try to go with VLAZ's comment. If I can answer it, I'll answer it. If it's answerable, I'll vote to reopen, even with zero-effort.

Comment: @jfriend00 Neither extreme is a good one. There are many of us that get helped by *existing* questions. Growth first with curation an afterthought makes it increasingly difficult to use [SO] as a Q&A repository. Merely focusing on the vocal question askers as "helping people" leaves out a significant part of people that are here to find helped and offer help as well.

Comment: @jabaa 0-effort has *never* been a valid close reason, period. Vote to reopen any closed as such provided it does not fall under standard close reasons. "no effort", though, is often indicative of a given post being closeable for other, valid, close reasons such as being a dupe (as no research comes hand in hand with duplication). I heavily edited the question you linked to remove trigger phrases, and it was, indeed, reopened via the standard procedure.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I didn't argue for an extreme either way.  But, the balance has tipped the wrong way.  A LOT of questions are getting slammed closed and recklessly marked as a dup (in the interest of curation) that does NOT help the OP, does not answer what they  were trying to ask.  That obviously isn't helping the OP and doesn't help SO either.  The pendulum has swung too far the other way.  It's out of balance and the effort is mostly by high rep users that are emphasizing curation over helping people.

Comment: @jfriend00 See, I'm having a hard time processing many of your recent comments. For example, your comment complains about *incorrect* dupe closure – something I can fully get behind as being bad. But then it attributes that to curation, and suddenly it is about a *general* issue of curation *versus* helping. Bad (duplicate) closure is *neither* curation *nor* helping. If you want to call out misuse or even abuse, please do so – but please do not equate it to curation, painting actual *helpful* curation efforts in a bad light by association.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - There are high rep users who spend a fair amount of effort curating new posts (closing them for one reason or another).  Sometimes those efforts are helpful to the OP (closing as a relevant dup that provides a solution to the OP).  Sometimes those efforts are not helpful at all to the OP (closing for the wrong reason or closing as a dup of something that does not help the OP).  I've seen more of the latter lately than I used to.  Something seems amiss in this trend.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - Here's one example from a couple days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905980/move-var-declarations-to-the-top-of-the-function-error.  My conclusion was that was closed for the wrong reason.  It should be a duplicate, not a "needs details", but the alarm bells went off when a high rep user who closed it said in a comment: "Didn't seem like a useful question to have around".  That is clearly a reference to closing it purely for long term curation reasons.

Comment: If only there was a way to remedy that problem

Comment: In this specific case, the linked question would *not* act as a useful sign post. Its title is the same. That doesn't excuse the incorrect closure, but it is an example of one worth deleting. Given it's worth deleting, i'd hesitate to reopen it and reclose it as a dupe, as then it won't be deleted without interaction from high rep users. The OP clearly has already been helped.

Comment: @KevinB I went for the pedantic route of finishing the reopen since it already had 2 reopen votes on it (so it was just a matter of time) and started reclose procedure for a dupe closure. Although given that the question has 0 value for the Q&A indeed, I am feeling like we collectively wasted too much time on it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Citing more anecdotes isn't going to change things – I already know that misuse and abuse happens in the name of curation, and I already think it's bad. Similarly, I already know that misuse and abuse happens in the name of answering, and I already think it's bad. But if you keep on painting this as "us versus them", as "helping versus curation" – well, then I'm not on your side, no matter if I wanted to.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - My only point is that there are examples of people prioritizing curation over helping and I think that's a problem when that happens.  I NEVER said that all curation is bad.  I just think some people get caught up in their zeal to curate and end up doing things that aren't actually good for users or the site.  I see this many times a day.  It's particularly common among questions by newish users and perhaps the staging ground will offer some help there (though I have my doubts).  It's also common among closing as a dup where the dup doesn't actually help the OP enough.

Comment: If the common frequently used dupe target is missing a more modern answer or an answer more targeted at newer users, the solution is to add an answer there, rather than trying to create a new canonical.

Comment: There's no question that providing an individualised answer to each and every question is the *best* way to help each and every OP, however, that misses helping those who aren't asking at all and instead are just searching, who will inevitably land on the most commonly viewed/targeted Q&A pair.