# How to deal with a number of questions pertaining to SEDE on Stack Overflow main

Tags: discussion, questions, data-explorer

A [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54523686#54523686) to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37115959) was posted in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) chat room which was about the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE). As it's about one of the details of the SEDE, a Stack Exchange component, I (and others) voted to close it saying it would be better on Meta.

For a one-off question, that's fine. However, when I searched Stack Overflow for ["sede"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sede), I was surprised by the number of questions that were specifically discussing SEDE details and queries.

How should we deal with these questions? Should they all be closed? The problem with that is that it seems to me like the total summed knowledge of them all really ought to be part of the Meta knowledge base. I would like to migrate them, but they're all too old to be migrated (at least by normal users; if mods can do it, I would think it a bad idea to spew out so many custom flags).

Comment: Counted 30 question from the 1st and 2nd pages of 10 total pages, and there are several more on the 3rd, at least.

Comment: No one (including mods) can migrate posts older than 60 days. Staff can (of course) but this very rare and not typically by request. I think my primary question is what makes you think that SEDE questions are always off topic for Stack Overflow? It does seem several of those are missing the tag [tag:dataexplorer]

Comment: @HenryEcker you raise a good point - they're not exactly off-topic. However, they're going to be much more useful on meta than on main for obvious reasons.

Comment: Sure I can agree that having all similar information together has value. That said we don't have a closure (or migration) reason for "while this is on topic here it would be better off somewhere else." Also what should happen all of the reputation associated with those posts (assuming they were moved to meta)?

Comment: @HenryEcker the rep would go, because the questions would be deleted.

Comment: I have to note that this is not strictly correct: reputation earned on 60+ days old posts with score >= 3 is [preserved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/786798).

Comment: More on point, I am not a fan of the idea of doing anything with those posts. Only those that are *specifically* about SEDE are off-topic on Stack Overflow main and should be closed as such - we should apply our standards of conduct to all posts.

Comment: If you are willing to go through each of the 570+ posts and separate those that have SEDE at their core from those that are made *in context* of the data explorer, be my guest - otherwise it is better to leave them alone.

Comment: I think the main thing to reason here is to only do something if it actually helps people. Say that an effort is made and the questions are moved over to meta. Who benefits? Let me rephrase that. Who actually searches on meta? Not many people, IMO. Meta posts exist so we can link people to them, they don't exists so people who have a question can find them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You deal with these questions as you would with any other question. Is the question on-topic for Stack Overflow, clear and answerable in its current form? If yes, do not vote to close.

> I (and others) voted to close it saying it would be better on meta.

Questions don't become off-topic because they are on-topic elsewhere. If that was your and others only reason to close vote that particular question then those close votes were cast in error.

> Should they all be closed? The problem with that is that it seems to me like the total summed knowledge of them all really ought to be part of the Meta knowledge base.

That argument can go both ways.

I'm a gold-badge holder in the [data-explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag over on Meta Stack Exchange. Looking at the number of answers where I provided a SQL query I would argue most of those questions should be closed and migrated to Stack Overflow.  After all, that is where the nifty T-SQL trickery needed in locked-down SQL Servers can become part of the total summed Stack Overflow knowledge base.

> I would like to migrate them

I don't. I don't want them, and Meta doesn't need them.

Comment: _"I would argue most of those questions should be closed and migrated to Stack Overflow"_ - Interesting view point; I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

**Not unless done properly**

Regardless of what we consider to be a *better* place to ask a question, the [guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417483/11407695) for closure is pretty clear on that part: if a post is on-topic on Stack Overflow, it *should not* be closed or migrated (with a caveat of the author explicitly asking to do so).

What makes a question tagged [sede](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sede) off-topic is being *explicitly* about how the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) works *in addition* to not asking about a unique programming problem. I am not sure there even *are* questions that fit that both criteria.

Even if a question is off-topic on Stack Overflow proper, you need to consider that Meta Stack Overflow is not the only and not the primary site for Data Explorer-related questions unless *scoped* to Stack Overflow. There are, at least 2 *more* suitable targets for general inquiries:

- Meta Stack Exchange (the [data-explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer?tab=Newest) tag)
- Stack Apps (the [data-explorer](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag)

Next, there is a flaw in your search query that results in a significant chunk of false positives. "Sede" is Italian for "site", whereas querying for the [dataexplorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataexplorer) tag yields more targeted results ([only 82](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdataexplorer%5D%20is%3Aq&searchOn=3) non-deleted posts at the time of this writing).

Finally, even for true positives, there is an issue that [migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) is simply not possible for posts older than 60 days, which leaves us with only [3 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdataexplorer%5D+created%3A2m..+is%3Aq&searchOn=1) at the moment.

Comment: I assume "Not unless done properly" is responding to the part of the question that specifically asks: "Should they all be closed?"

Comment: You raise another question in my mind: [tag:dataexplorer] is a pretty bad tag name for the main site...

Comment: @richardec well, it's sort of O.K. given that it is the name of the technology and thus not much different from other tags like [tag:google-sheets], etc. However, I agree there are issues. I'd rename it to [tag:stack-exchange-data-explorer] for starters.

Comment: @V2Blast kind of - it's a bit of an awkward response to "how to deal" title :)