# How can I indicate that a particular question has already been asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I found some similar questions on this platform and I want to point it out, how should I go about it?

Comment: If it is a duplicate, there is a flag as a duplicate option. If you are not sure, then you can mention in the comments since you have the privilege to comment anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance). In particular, read through the guidance on duplicate closure

Answer (score 6):

Flag it as a duplicate.  If enough people agree with the duplicate closure, then the question will *automatically* display this at the very top, and add [duplicate] to the title.

Comment: Makes me wonder where duplicate flags end up. It puts the question in close vote review?