# What's up with the [regex] tag? It seems many on-topic [regex] tag were removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I'm checking question that tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), but most of the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tags were removed shortly.

[image]

Is this tag still used? I checked the usage of the tag; it doesn't look like an abuse. Many questions are on-topic with language/tools specified. Is there a specific reason? What is the correct way to use the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag?

Some of the examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76515599/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76511797/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76511435/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76506454/revisions

Comment: The removal of [tag:regex] tag on [post #76515599](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76515599/revisions) looks correct since the title asks about "Perl one-liner" (the X) while the body mentions Regex (the Y). Even the accepted answer is not using Regex.

Comment: I think the user is trying to remove the regex tag from questions which either: 1) Don't specifically ask for solutions using regex 2) Can be solved with solutions other than regex as well. Some of the edits seem valid to me, not so sure about some of the others though.

Comment: The RegEx tag is a cesspool of pedantic infighting and people churning out answers as if they were regex101.com themselves. Ignore the tag and live a happier life.

Comment: My gut reaction is that removing the tag makes sense when OP is tunnel-visioned on solving a problem with regex where it isn't appropriate (XY problem), or where the problem as described at least has totally reasonable non-regex solutions (even if regex also makes sense). Certainly it shouldn't be removed if the question is "why doesn't the regex do what I expect?" - although most of those definitely need more focus or debugging details.

Comment: @Karl that's not how tags and community edits work. If it were, I would remove every C# tag and say "this is easier to do using JavaScript". It just makes no sense. _If_ a question is better answered by a non-regex answer, then ask in comments whether that's acceptable, don't go removing the regex tag because you (not literally you but the general you) think it's a bad fit for the question at hand.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, that makes perfect sense for c#, but regex isn't a language in the same way C# is. it as a tag can be relevant to nearly every language that exists, but that doesn't mean it belongs on every question where a user decided to abuse regex to solve a problem that could be better solved using the language they're applying it to.

Comment: I side with @KevinB here. Fundamentally, language tags are different from technique/library/tool tags. Unfortunately, the system does not represent this difference.

Comment: Meta: What about the question? There is a "regex" tag on MSO. [A sample](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460).

Comment: @AndrewT. I (barely) agree with the removal of the tag on that question but I’ll note that the accepted answer *does* use regex. That regex happens to be a literal string without regex metacharacters, true. But *it is still a regex*, and [Perl treats it as a regex pattern](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#The-Basics).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't see that being tunnel-visioned on solving with regex makes it appropriate to remove the regex tag. By all means let them know they can solve with without regex, but if it's a question about regex, it's a question about regex. Even if the question is of the X/Y variety, unless it's edited, it's still a question about regex and the regex tag is appropriate. _Even if_ the best answer is "don't do it with regex" it's still a question about regex. Tags are applied to the question and the question alone, regardless of answers.

Comment: This kind of *"curation"* is so annoying to me (more than spam, even) that I had to hit the rollback button, and break my strike for a couple of minutes. Won't get to an editing war if they decide to edit again though.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ Rolling back only 4 edits won't even make a dent in years worth of edits. The reason  edits like these are done without opposition is because opposing requires significant time.

Comment: @TheMaster definitely not. I was just annoyed, but still on strike. And I've been rolling back these edits for years, yet couldn't keep up with them. As you said, it needs significant time and effort.

Comment: p.s.  I was hoping to see an answer from the user themselves. Maybe they can convince us that their edits are valid or we can get them to stop.

Comment: Blue-skying for a moment here: If the regex tag were split off to a separate SE site, how much traffic might it generate? What if it had a deliberately seeded set of canonicals for fundamentals (down to the level of "how do I make a pattern to match A followed by B" etc.)?

Answer (score 38):

It appears this user is using adding and removing tags to answer the question, which is not how this site works.

If the OP wants a regex, then post a regex answer. If you want to tell them that they're trying to solve their original problem with a suboptimal solution and ask whether an alternative is viable, then ask that using comments. Don't go editing the question's tags.

At https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76515599/revisions, the user in question removed [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and added [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/split), as a way of saying "I would split the string instead of using a regular expression", for example. That's just not how it works.

Comment: Linked question has nothing to do with regex. OP asked for one liner, and provided their attempt, that happen to use regex. How is it regex question in your opinion?

Comment: _"Linked question has nothing to do with regex"_ - the oneliner OP came up with to solve their task _being_ a regular expression would prove otherwise.

Comment: As I stated in my answer,  I don't think that mere usage of regex in current attempt makes question regex related. In the same way we don't tag every question using foreach with said tag. Would question  state that they answer should to be regex related, or at least something of the manner "how can i correctmy regex, to acomolish described", retaining wouldn't be warranted. But this exact question isn't the case.

Comment: _"state that they answer should to be regex related, or at least something of the manner "how can i correctmy regex, to acomolish described""_ - ... that is exactly what a regex tag and an approach using a regex shown imply. It means _"How can I let this regex, or a slightly modified version thereof, do what I want it to"_.

Comment: We shouldn't have a oneliner tag in the first place, for the same reason that the Code Golf site was split off.

Comment: @Karl the code being a oneliner also is irrelevant. One can run `php -r 'echo preg_replace(...)'` and poof it's a regex question.

Comment: IMO sometimes it is actually beneficial to remove the regex tag as long as it doesn't change the aim of the asker. For example I remember some time ago there was a question which was trying to find list comprehensions in python code. The OP tried to approach it using regex, and the question got closed for lacking clarity. Without the regex tag this question was in fact quite clear (there was even a duplicate target). Reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420050/how-can-i-make-my-question-more-clear#420050

Comment: @Abdul I'm sorry but none of this makes sense to me. As soon as someone shows a regex in their question, it's a regex question. If there are solutions without regex, then post that as answer. Or first ask in comments whether that's acceptable. We're not just here for the OP, but also for later visitors.

Comment: @CodeCaster agreed we're not here just for the OP but for the later visitors as well. Which is why an artificial constraint just due to OPs initial thoughts for a solution shouldn't matter. If the question says "I want to do XYZ and.have attempted to use the following regex", that attempt can be said to be irrelevant. If there are solutions without regex we should be posting those. But the presence of the tag is taken as an constraint that only regex solutions are welcome.

Comment: It's up to the OP to lift that constraint by not using the regex tag or editing it out.

Answer (score 34):

I've seen the user removing the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) regularly on questions which the user thinks are of low quality. I believe they're using tag removal as a shorter alternative to closing the questions (which requires consensus), to avoid seeing the questions that they disagree with on their watchlist.

To be clear, not all their tag removals were invalid, but some clearly are, and they're done regularly without any opposition.

Comment: If this is a common "problem" then I suppose the question seems to be has anyone flagged one of the user's posts to raise that they are (ab)using the edit feature. Moderators won't be aware I less a flag is raised and this answer implies it's been ahppening for a bit. Unfortunately, we have ko way of knowing, but one would have one hoped someone would have flagged it; having 6k reputation or 600k reputation doesn't make ones behaviour acceptable if it goes against the sites rules/consensus (which it seems to be here).

Comment: @ThomA I highly doubt that the moderators knew nothing about this - given the near daily edits for over at least a year or two. But, even if mods were  somehow unaware, this meta post does expose the issue to the public and moderators. However, most of active mods are on strike and therefore I don't think we can expect any action in the near future. Also, 600k rep does count a lot(in user's minds) when taking any adverse steps(like flagging) against the user(especially, when those reps were not gained through spamming answers, but providing good quality answers).

Comment: I'm not sure about the intention of the editor. Maybe it's a good deed to do since `regex` tag may draw attentions from uses who only know `regex` itself but not the programming languages / tools. Which I assume their answers may not work in that environment (but I don't think it's that much of a problem). But on the other hand, we might as well just ban this tag instead of having an *overlord* to do it for us just by merely his own personal taste.

Comment: @HaoWu should we also ban SQL since it has different flavors? The presumed good deed has nothing to do with the fact that their edits are wrong and should be reversed in many cases (not always). The "overlord", as you referred to them, is actually making more work for us. All that said, this user is an extremely helpful contributor in terms of providing answers. Just a bit too aggressive with their moderation privileges.

Comment: "*Just a bit too aggressive with their moderation privileges.*", yep, my Opinion also, last example I checked a few hours ago ([Java Regex to reduce line feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76543697/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) (Link is to the 'Timeline')), => Qt asked with "Regex" in the Title, OP asking for a 'Regex' Solution, 2 Answers (with Regex) posted within 1 hour, (+4 Accepted & +1), Gold Badge User removed the 'Regex' Tag 20 min later, +1 more Regex Answer a few hours later... // Feels a bit to me like this User absolutely wants to protect their Top1 Position in the Tag...

Comment: @chivracq I wouldn't say that. They are way ahead of everyone in the "game" to be intimated :) I just think they have a slightly different/skewed view of tags, edits, and dupe-hammering.

Comment: @M--, the removal of the 'Regex' Tag in that Thread/Qt was completely inexplicable to me (oh...!, has since been reversed by some other High-Rep User, who agreed with me apparently (1st part))... // "*inexplicable*" then tja, "people" (and I) try go looking for some plausible explanation, => find (a better) one for this specific Thread/Qt...? Absolutely everything in the Thread was about 'Regex', why remove it...!? (and replace it with vaguely appropriate Tags)... Sorry, but this is not a "Mistake" or a "skewed View"...

Comment: @chivracq I see what you're saying. One explanation could be that they may think if regex is not the right/best solution for the problem, they can convey that message by removing the tag. I don't agree with that approach, but that's an alternative explanation for their actions (also see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425287/whats-up-with-the-regex-tag-it-seems-many-on-topic-regex-tag-were-removed/425301?noredirect=1#comment963132_425299). BTW, I meant to write intimidated in my previous comment (not intimated, lol).

Comment: @M--, oh...!, I had indeed read your "*intimated*" as "intimidated" without even noticing...! // "*One explanation could be that they may think if regex is not the right/best solution for the problem*", hum, I don't believe this to be *true*, I answer a small Tag where the 'Regex' Tag sometimes is added/relevant because of Users asking for a 'Regex' Sol, and each time I provided a non-'Regex' Sol, but the Tag is small and my Answers rarely go above +1, and that Gold Tag holder (nearly) never removed the 'Regex' Tag... (Only once I think I remember, but that was already 2 or 3 years ago...)

Answer (score 10):

Nothing's up, the [phenomenon has been known for over two years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405460/6574038). Apparently, it is appreciated as a curative behavior.

You need a thick skin when answering on [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex): tag removal, question closure, even deletion is likely to occur as is downvoting (but also upvoting) your valuable answer. If the question is deleted, so are the votes.

At least the process takes a while, so you can be sure that you have helped the asker and learned something yourself, and that is what really counts ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm obviously not the user who edited the posts in question, and I don't know his thought process.

But here is my assumption on how questions should or shouldn't be tagged with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex):

- if the question is a problem with specific regular expression, for example if I want to match only words beginning with upper letter, is should be tagged with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).
- if the question is a problem that has nothing to do with regex, like split by delimiter like in first linked revision, it shouldn't be tagged with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

The mere fact that OP used regex in their attempt doesn't automatically make the question about regex.

I can't say that I 100% agree with edits by said user. For example, I don't understand the fourth linked revision. But generaly I see logic in these edits, and tend to agree most of the time.

Comment: As soon as someone tries to solve a problem using a regular expression and needs help with that, that question is ipso facto about a regular expression. That you wouldn't or that they shouldn't use a regex for that, is moot and should not result in the removal of said tag.

Comment: In ideal world - of cause use of some tag means exactly that. But we are not in ideal world. Many users add tag regex solely based on fact that they used regex in their attempt. IMO, this is not sufficient criteria for usage of this (or any other) tag, exactly for the reason in my other comment: mere usage of foreach, loops, variables and classes in your attempt shouldn't result in adding corresponding tags to the question. cc @CodeCaster

Comment: @markalex if you're attempting to get the regex to work, as opposed to finding an alternative to it, *of course* it makes sense to use the regex tag.  Same applies to the other examples you used.

Comment: @MarkRansom, sure. But it doesn't apply to first three links in question, IMO. Because it were attempts to make "code" work in general.

Comment: Downvote. Regardless of whether a user is asking how to solve a problem with regex that should be solved without, if they're asking about regex, they're asking about regex. You don't get to change what they're asking just because it's a silly question. By all means let them know they can solve it more easily without regex, or even give them a non-regex answer, but don't remove the regex tag.