# Abuse of privileges? A moderator locked my question and removed all my edits and our back and forth discussion on whether my question is duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, abuse, moderator-abilities

### Backstory (**NOT ENTIRELY RELEVANT TO THE REAL QUESTION**)

I believe my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76518227/python-regex-doesnt-match-when-adding-additional-text-around-pattern-and-text) isn't a duplicate, but a moderator does (note: I do *not* care whether you believe it was a duplicate or not). I created edits explaining why my question might not be a duplicate, and the moderator continues to rollback my hard work and edits, saying that meta discussion should not be on my post. Replying, I quoted the duplicate notice passage, saying that I should "edit [my] question to highlight the difference between the associated question and [mine]. If edited, [my] question will be reviewed and might be reopened." However, this moderator stayed adamant, refusing to listen.

### Important bit:

The moderator deleted my apologies to the answer writers about their reputation loss (someone was downvoting for no reason). Next, he proceeded to lock my question and delete all our discussion.

### The question: (I'm not asking about whether my question is a duplicate or not)

***Regardless*** of whether my question was a duplicate or not, is this abuse of moderator privileges? I should be able to voice my own opinions.

Comment: Be careful to make sure you know the difference between a moderator and a curator. Wiktor is a curatior, dharman is a moderator. You can tell by the diamond next to dharman's name, and the lack of one next to wiktor's.

Comment: No, it's not abuse. Repeatedly rolling back noisy edits, on the other hand, _is_ abuse.

Comment: *"I should be able to voice my own opinion and this moderator simply shut it all down"* what are you doing here if not voicing your opinion..?

Comment: @ThomA You're exactly right, this is the only place where I can, not a locked post. But these two posts deserve to be linked in some way to be relevant to my original post.

Comment: Because a question on [so] isn't a place for opinions and discussion. The system worked! 

Comment: there's more people that can handle curation on your post than just the person who previously did so. (well, until it got locked due to your repeated edits, that is)

Comment: You didn't explain the dupe closure, you added meta commentary, and then kept editting it back **after** a moderator removed it. That was your *hint* that the edit you did was wrong. A *different* and correct edit would have not been rolled back. Rolling back a moderator's action is only asking for a post to be locked.

Comment: This would usually be linked to your original question, when someone adds a (temporary) comment linking it(usually done), but since it is locked, it is not possible now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, I read that, and did what it said. I voted to reopen and edited my post. It's my bad for not "understanding" what the closure meant, but still, I'm not asking about whether my question is a duplicate or not.

Comment: After reading your edits in the edit history, I would also add: the banner specifically says " This question has answers here"(Not this question is a  exact duplicate of that question) and "A community member has **associated** this post with a similar question.".  Regarding "your question adding value", it still adds value. It won't be deleted as long as it has a answer  with +1. Nothing changed except there's a banner on top of your question linking it to another question and no more answers can be posted to your question.

Comment: @TheMaster ok, I guess I'll take that then  If it adds value I'm fine, but it could be better

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, please don't suggest that as a duplicate. I don't want the same thing to happen all over again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question will be closed as duplicate also. But for the record, I don't agree with this closure..

Comment: If you understand downvotes as "toxic" and upvotes as "welcoming" then I'm afraid you misunderstand them. Up/down votes are a content rating system to denoting if the post was useful and/or helpful. There's nothing about "welcoming" attached to them. I'd go as far as to say that using a vote to (un)welcome a user to the community is misuse of the votes; the vote is targeting the user not the content.

Comment: No one has "hated" on you. The community has attempted to explain why what you did was received poorly, by a moderator, and why the post was locked as a result; we've tried to help by explaining that. If you don't like those reasons is your decision, but that doesn't change the way the community treats bad edits.

Comment: Comments calling you dumb would be a violation of the code of conduct, so please feel free to flag such incidences when they happen.

Comment: @ThomA Off topic note and probably related to OP's question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions/402486#comment948415_402486

Comment: Disagreeing with you is not "hate". You requested community input, and you have received it. Please flag any _actual_ hate for moderator attention, though do note that moderation capacity on the main site is [severely reduced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000/208273) at the moment, so flags there may take a while to handle.  Do not continue to levy baseless accusations of conspiracy (accusing users of summoning backup, etc.) and hate in the comments.  If there are actual Code of Conduct violations, you may flag them, but remember that _disagreement_ is not a Code of Conduct violation.

Comment: posts on meta generally receive more attention than posts, on main site. On main most users browse only tags they are interested in, here, due to lower volume of questions, most users see every question. Plus, I have to agree with all other commenters: I don't see anything even remotely resembling hate. Comments explaining how you made a mistake are not hate. I'd even say they are love, because they (intended to) help you avoid such mistakes in future.

Comment: Tangentially related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425334 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460

Comment: It is that tag again. See e.g. *[What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/)* and [from *What's up with the \[regex\] tag? It seems many on-topic \[regex\] tag were removed?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425287/whats-up-with-the-regex-tag-it-seems-many-on-topic-regex-tag-were-removed#comment962885_425287) (only three days ago): *"Wiktor Stribiżew isn't a mod. A mod can be identified by having [♦Mod] adjacent to their name, like Cody above does."*

Comment: And from *[What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries#comment827145_405460)*: *"I admit that I (a fairly high rep user) am afraid to post questions in the regex tag. My first question in that tag got attacked (and I deleted it). I was a ~30K rep user at the time. Since then I have felt that you needed to be really really sure you had an extra extra good and worthy question before posting one in the regex tag. (Basically, if a tag could be considered "unfriendly", then that tag is."*

Comment: Side note: I thought this was the kind of question ChatGPT would be able to answer. But no: Using the exact prompt *"Regular expression: Why does the following Python code not result in a match? "re.match(r"Python (\d.)+\d (64-bit) Setup", "Python 3.11.4 (64-bit) Setup")""*, it responded with (not all of the verbose response is included here) *"The reason why the given regular expression does not result in a match is because of the use of the dot (.) within the group (\d.)+."*. I tried to ask a leading question: *"That is not all. What else?"*

Comment: cont' - Response: *"Besides the incorrect usage of the dot (.), there is another problem with the expression. The problem lies with the use of the parentheses around (\d.)+."*. Its resolution is probably(?) not what we are looking for: *"To resolve this, you can use re.search() instead of re.match()."*. Or perhaps it is a creative one? Asked about a solution in Perl it failed completely (forgetting about the issue with the parentheses). Another leading question fixed it (but that is already knowing the solution): *"Are you sure it matches?"*

Comment: @markalex I think that posts with words like "abuse", "privileges", "closed", "duplicate", etc. tend to be received worse on this site than others.

Comment: I would say that posts with tone like this question has are received poorly on this site. Mere presence of said word doesn't result in said receivement.

Comment: "(I'm not asking about whether my question is a duplicate or not)" - That's fine. **Regardless of whether or not we think your question is a duplicate in this case**, if you disagree with such an assessment (whether by a moderator or by the community) in general, you should not act as you did, and **existing questions on meta**, like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521, explain how you should act instead and why. More importantly, see the cross-site (main SE meta) duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476

Comment: On the other hand - if you're actually trying to ask "Should moderators be allowed to stop me from repeatedly rolling back edits, and should they be allowed to remove discussion and meta commentary from questions (which are not supposed to contain those things)?" - then the answer is so obviously "yes" that I genuinely can't understand why you're asking.

Comment: "I think that posts with words like "abuse", "privileges", "closed", "duplicate", etc. tend to be received worse on this site than others" - I agree. That's because they overwhelmingly come from people who have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the site works. This is **not a discussion forum**, and the purpose of questions here **is not** to get your individual problem resolved, but to contribute to a high-quality Q&A library.

Comment: Why are there 4 reopen votes on this? What exactly is anyone hoping to accomplish by allowing further answers? More callouts of OP's poor conduct?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Can't speak for the rest of the reopen votes, but I am disgusted by users closing questions incorrectly as duplicates, just to shut users down... The question is about abuse of moderator privileges... the question explicitly says it's not about the duplicate closing ...but it is still closed as "what to do when my question is not a duplicate".  I'm not sure about the original SO question, but closing this meta question is a absolute disgusting abuse of power.

Comment: @TheMaster No; OP said that the question isn't about whether the original question was a duplicate. It *is* still, fundamentally, about *how to behave when you dispute that fact*. OP's behaviour was *clearly* wrong, but OP wants to find fault with the moderator instead. The linked duplicate explains proper conduct for these situations; if any further explanation is required about moderator conduct, it either belongs there, is covered by other questions, or is covered by the site's help section. But no, there is no "abuse of power" here because there is no reason for the question to stay open.

Comment: Again: the alternative way to interpret the question is that the underlying question is "Should moderators be allowed to stop me from repeatedly rolling back edits, and should they be allowed to remove discussion and meta commentary from questions (which are not supposed to contain those things)?". And, again, that doesn't even deserve a response, because it's kind of like asking "should the sky really be allowed to be blue?".

Comment: Normally, people complain about Stack Overflow because they don't understand the ways that our community is different; but these sorts of moderator actions *wouldn't be out of place anywhere else, either*. My assessment is that this can't be seen as a good-faith question seeking an understanding of policy; it's instead a veiled rant or protest from someone who is clearly in the wrong.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You're assuming malintent on the part of the OP, but you want OP not to do the same  with the moderators or other users. How is that fair? Why does your opinion on other users intentions hold more weight than that of OP's? If we don't want users to assume malintent on the part of moderators or other users, I believe we should lead by example, and assume good faith.  Let's stick to the facts and not intentions, or seeing things behind the veil('veiled rant'), because behind the veil, you see what you want to see. Sticking to the facts, I believe the duplicate closure is incorrect.

Comment: Just like you, If I do see behind the veil, this question closure is nothing but a clear abuse of power.

Comment: "You're assuming malintent on the part of the OP" - no, no I am not. To the extent that my argument alleges bad intent, it's based on the evidence available to me, and on common-sense arguments about conduct that apply to every moderated Internet space (e.g. if a moderator explicitly and demonstrably objects to what you are doing, *it would be a bad idea to keep doing that thing*; and if you go to the meta space to complain about the moderation of a place you just joined, you *should write from a perspective that properly accounts for the possibility that you don't understand the culture*).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The OP clearly gave his reasons to think why they thought the moderator was abusing his privileges. Granted they don't know the culture and the intent of moderator's actions, but unless you're assuming bad intent on their part, how are you suggesting that they don't *account for the possibility that you don't understand the culture*?  Didn't the question state "Is this a abuse of moderator privileges"? If you assume good faith, you  it's simply a open ended question asking  for clarification and a explanation[1/2]

Comment: If you think that doesn't even deserve a answer or that it is  asking "should the sky really be allowed to be blue?", downvote and move on. Just don't add a distantly related question as a duplicate just to close down the question. Isn't that what the original dispute in the SO question was about? Isn't it adding insult to injury? I see this more as abuse of power than anything else. This Meta culture has to change, but I highly doubt meta's ability to admit any wrongdoing [2/2]

Comment: @TheMaster "The OP clearly gave his reasons to think why they thought the moderator was abusing his privileges." - could you please briefly restate what reasons you believe OP gave? What I'm getting out of it is "I put a lot of work into writing the post and the moderator didn't care and told me not to do certain things, and then repeatedly removed my content when I tried to restore it". Is that an actual reason that actual people actually believe a moderator abuse of power occurred?

Comment: I don't think the other question is "distantly related". I think it very precisely explains what OP did wrong, and what to do better in the future. Answering this **inherently shows** that the OP **did** something wrong, which **inherently answers** the question of whether the moderator abused power by specifically pointing out the things OP did wrong and attempting to fix them (i.e.: no).

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Two things:

1. The dupe-voter was not a moderator, but a gold tag badge holder who can unilaterally close questions as duplicate for questions tagged with said tag.
2. A moderator rolled back your unnecessary *explanation of what a duplicate is*, because that's not *explaining why your question isn't a duplicate*. Slight difference in words, big in implications.

Now the dupe-voter is a user who causes unnecessary friction because they're trying to bend the site rules their way. See [What's up with the [regex] tag? It seems many on-topic [regex] tag were removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425287/whats-up-with-the-regex-tag-it-seems-many-on-topic-regex-tag-were-removed/425298#425298) for another evaluation of their behavior by me.

They have posted over 20K answers in the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag. Answering that many questions causes people to get bored of seeing the same question over and over again. You aren't gonna convince me that there are no duplicate answers in those 20K, but they still don't like certain (simple?) questions repeated. That's their problem, not yours.

The *answer* to your question comes down to something along the lines of:

> If you want to match a string `(foo)` in a regular expression, you must escape the parentheses in the expression: `\(foo\)`.

Pretty simple, and I'm sure that with a little searching you can find a Q&A that explain this. **If you know that that's the issue**. If you don't, and you get linked to [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions) instead, you'll have to do the mental jump from *"Why isn't my regex working"* to *"I must have not escaped what I should have or vice versa"*.

Again, that's fine **if you know**, but if you don't, it isn't.

They appear to be trying to create a kind of "RTFM" culture, treating the linked question as the chapter about escaping. I mean: look at [the 286 other questions linked to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/399078?lq=1). That's cute, but not how this site works.

So:

1. You've been unlucky to need regex help.
2. You should not have gone and complained about what you think a duplicate is, but instead explained what part of the duplicate you didn't understand.
3. If the mods weren't on strike, I'd beg them to have a hearty heart-to-heart talk with the given user. You can still try by custom mod flagging your question. Make sure to be specific.

Comment: Wow, 286, that's insane. I guess I'm not the only one. Something interesting is that some posts are positive in voting while others are negative.

Comment: Some of that won't be unique to [[tag:Regex]]. Unfortunately some tags do also garner a lot of low quality posts, and some of those end up deleted quite quickly (so you won't be able to see them). With the strike on at the moment, however, many of these posts may not actually be getting the downvotes they normally would. It's a known "phenomenon" that the quality of posts feels like it's declining. (This comment is not discussing the quality of your posts and it should not be read that way.)

Comment: (re: deleted comment asking why this was downvoted) I haven't downvoted it, but I'm considering downvoting it mainly because asking for code is how Stack Overflow works; an attempt is not required and generally makes questions less useful.  The first paragraph teaches people the wrong thing about Stack Overflow.

Comment: It also does seem to be _mostly_ a duplicate.  The primary issue in your question is that you failed to escape some parentheses (also the period, but that didn't cause it).  That has nothing to do with "adding additional text around pattern and text"; it has to do with the fact that what you added missed an escape.  There's also the fact that you didn't write the quantifier after the `\d`; that's arguably a typo, although arguably "it doesn't match the whole string" is a generally useful explanation to other people with similar issues, but that seems secondary to the parentheses issue here.

Comment: The regex tag *does* have some problems with misuse of RTFM-style dupe closures, although I don't think this is a particularly bad example of it.  (Mods have tried to discourage it before the strike, though we have limited time generally, especially with the influx of AI-generated crap.)

Comment: The hasty deletion of regex questions has been brought up (although without a clear decision on how to handle them) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate, but any potential situation of regex questions being inappropriately closed as too broad a duplicate is something that would merit its own question, _without calling out the one person who is seemingly one of the very few curators_ of that tag. You are doing us no favours with this individual shaming.

Comment: It is true that it's virtually impossible to answer questions in the regex tag without this particular user strong-arming the thread one way or the other in a way that feels less like curation, and more like wiring things up so they have total control over the tag. I gave up answering in the regex tag years ago, and a disproportionate volume of my deleted answers are in the tag. Almost all of those deletions are from this lone wolf. That said, they're sometimes on target with their curation actions and this may be one such case.

Comment: @Ryan alright, I've edited that part out to not let it distract from my main point. I still believe in regex it is more important than elsewhere to show your work. Because regular expressions have like five basic components and maybe as many modifiers, the product thereof would therefore fit in 25 "how-to" questions. Regex questions are either debugging questions, or it is a tag where we do accept "I have this string, give me the expression to match $part". That is _not_ equal to "how to do $concept". Each input string is different; many, many patterns match.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah, it's a real problem & I'm not sure there's a great solution. The old "too localized" close reason did have some real applicability in regex, but...probably wasn't worth the problems it caused. Certainly most "here is a list of requirements" regex Qs aren't useful to anyone other than the asker (and they're often homework or interview-type Qs explicitly designed to be hard to look up), and an attempt _rarely_ makes them better. For instance, here there were 2 unrelated errors; the chances of someone having that exact combination of errors *and finding that question* seems low.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike Sorry, but I think you misunderstand. I never said Dharman's name out loud. I only referred to him as "a moderator". I'm not taking his actions personally.

Comment: It appears that I'm being misinterpreted, rather than the other way around. I was directing my comment to this answer in particular, as a warning not to make this about an individual witch hunt for Wiktor.

Comment: @E_net4 I want to call out this user because of their behavior. Why wouldn't I? Or: in what other way than posting an answer under a Meta question asking for an explanation of their behavior would I be able to do this? Everyone is to be held to the site standards, 6 rep or 600K.

Comment: "If you don't, and you get linked to What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions? instead, you'll have to do the mental jump from "Why isn't my regex working" to "I must have not escaped what I should have or vice versa"." - ew, no. Questions like "why doesn't X regex work?" "why doesn't Y regex work?" "why doesn't Z regex work?", when the *reason all of them don't work is because something needs to be escaped and isn't*, are not viable. There are arbitrarily many such regexes, and exactly one cause. The canonical could *possibly be modified* to smooth over that mental jump.

Comment: "I want to call out this user because of their behavior." - generally speaking, I am sympathetic to the concerns raised in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425287. But *in this case*, Wiktor has clearly done nothing wrong (aside from not being on strike ;) ). When I was closing duplicates, I would make equivalent closures in the Python tag all the time, with (as far as I can tell, from e.g. talking about it in the Python chat room) broad community support.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse "For instance, here there were 2 unrelated errors; the chances of someone having that exact combination of errors and finding that question seems low." - well, yes. There is next to zero chance that someone in OP's situation will be able to find existing useful information - on Stack Overflow *or anywhere else on the Internet* - without assistance from more knowledgeable human guides, exactly because of the unknown unknowns. There is no way, from OP's perspective, to suss out the general pattern of the problem. (1/3)

Comment: However, duplicate closures like this one **are the exact human intervention that solves that problem**, and one of the primary services Stack Overflow can provide. Compare to if the same question were asked on a traditional discussion forum; experts responding could a) get frustrated at yet another noob; b) write an explanation from scratch of the same concept for the Nth time; c) copy and paste from a sticky/reference thread; d) link to said thread. Stack Overflow's design is intended to normalize the d) approach to avoid both frustration and clutter. (2/3)

Comment: Of course, that only addresses the "missing escapes for parentheses" issue. The "missing quantifier" - well, there *might* be a separate duplicate for that, but it's either a typo or else a separate problem *that should be in a separate question*. Yes, there's an issue with regex in that a simple string can have multiple unrelated things wrong with it. **That doesn't obviate OPs of the expectation** to research the problem by *analyzing* what goes wrong, *breaking the problem down* into parts and *locating a single point of failure* - in other words, attempting basic debugging. (3/3)

Comment: It seems to me like the main issue here is that the canonical is written as a "reference-level" Q&A, but a "tutorial-level" Q&A would be much more practical. As inspiration for motivated, non-striking users: the title might be something like "How do I make a regex to match a literal string? Why can't I directly match certain characters?"

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike oh ok, my bad.

Answer (score 28):

I was the moderator who handled the dispute on your question.

I removed the edit and explained to you in the comment section what you should do instead. You didn't listen and rolled it back. I had no other option but to lock the post. I was hoping you would come to meta with your concerns as you just did.

You should not be allowed to voice your opinions on the main site. The main site isn't the place for that. If you want to discuss your post, do it on the meta site.

In regards to votes and your comments that followed: I didn't vote on any answer or the question. Don't assume you know who voted. The comments you added were absolutely inappropriate as you were apologizing for something that should not require any apologies. Downvotes are not dislikes and they are not bad. **In fact that is the only way you can express your opinion on the main site**. Don't take votes personally as they only reflect our opinion of the post.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But why did you delete the discussion and what about the first paragraph of the explanation?

Comment: I deleted the discussion because it was a discussion. You read my messages and I read yours. It was over and the comments were no longer needed.

Comment: And what did you think about my first paragraph?

Comment: Do you mean "*Hi, so I see that this question has been marked as a duplicate of*"? This has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: The other sentences were unnecessary. If you want to say the answer(s) to the duplicate, do not answer your question, and explain the reason those answers did not resolve your problem that would have been fine.  What you did instead was add 6 paragraphs of commentary on the reason it wasn't a duplicate. You complained instead of providing a simple explanation of the reason the answers were not a duplicate.  A question is a duplicate, when an answer already exists, and can reasonably be determine also answers the new question.

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't trying to be rude. When I said nothing I meant that it doesn't explain why the suggestion from the duplicate target doesn't apply to your regex question. The question should never contain any greetings or descriptions of the question asking process itself.

Comment: "Also, please try not to be rude when you say the word "nothing"." -- what the... And then people wonder why so many of us hesitate making any comments when curating the site. | Why apologise, Dharman, you've done nothing even remotely wrong.

Comment: And you don't need to assume bad faith from an innocuous sentence, but here we are...

Comment: You *asked people for their opinion*, by posting this question on Meta, and now you're complaining that they're giving it to you? No one is calling your ideas dumb and incomprehensive... They're saying the edits to your question did not add information, and that they disagree with your claim that the question is not a duplicate. No, it's not normal or natural to perceive any of this as rude. Downvotes are never rude. Of course, no one is saying you made any mistakes *on purpose*. However, *you* rolled in with claims of "abuse of privileges", so that puts people on the defensive.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Please, stop prolonging useless discussion. I'm not a troll. Stop. I don't like to argue with people online. I would like to quote this however: "The question: (I'm not asking about whether my question is a duplicate or not)". I don't disagree that my question may have been a duplicate. That is very subjective, and I don't care whether you believe it is or not.

Comment: I think there's some confusion on your part. Stack Overflow is not a social network; we are a technical Q&A platform. Both posts and comments should be objective in nature, and anything that does not contribute to the analysis of the raised problem should be considered noise and therefore avoided. The feedback you perceive as personal is actually a cold, emotionless analysis based on the site's rules. Of course, there are some trolls on the site, as there are everywhere in life, but that's not the case here—it's just objectivity.

Comment: If you haven't figured it out already. The answer to your question is No, there was no abuse from a moderator and all actions were completely appropriate for the situation. And that does not include closing the question as duplicate, because this was not done by a moderator and you also don't seem to be interested in that part.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, I have taken the loss, from the surprisingly high 322 viewers and four moderators, all telling me the same thing (I guess words like "Abuse" and "privileges" really made this post blow up?). "ok, I guess I'll take that then  If it adds value I'm fine, but it could be better" - Me.

Comment: You put text in your question that does not belong there, then you rolled back edits several time and then mod interfered and locked the post. This is standard procedure, don't take it personally. When your question gets closed as duplicate (regardless whether it was valid closure or not), you should edit it in a way that clarifies the question itself, not by adding text that says this is not duplicate and similar.

Comment: In your case duplicate mentioned escaping characters that you didn't escaped. The proper course would be escaping those and see what happens. If the problem is solved fine, then it was indeed duplicate, if not, then you have another problem, but it is no longer a duplicate of that question. Having said that if the question has multiple issues, it is possible that people close it as duplicate because of single issue, even though there are more issues. Questions with multiple issues usually hold less value for future readers, so they remain closed regardless. It is still worth trying to improve.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ok.

Answer (score 26):

Your edit does nothing to improve the question or differentiate it from the duplicate target. If you feel the dupe closure is incorrect and no edit would fix that, your options are: leave a comment with an @ targeting the user who closed it, or opening a [specific-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) post here on MSO to discuss it.

**No mod abuse occurred in this case given you repeatedly edited in the same irrelevant content into your question.** A lock, as done in this case, has effectively ended that rollback war and forced you to take the latter action... so it seems to be doing it's job?

Comment: Um, no, I simply followed the dupe closure and quoted it to the moderator but he wouldn't listen and he continued to rollback my changes. I highlighted the difference in the first paragraph of my edits.

Comment: You added meta-commentary, that isn't what belongs in a question. YOu didn't edit the question to appropriate demonstrate why it's not a duplicate. Text like *"so I see that this question has been marked as a duplicate"* has no business being in a question. YOu quoted a blog that is *irrelevant* to the question you asked.

Comment: I can see your edits in the edit history, the entire 6 paragraph entry does nothing to explain why it isn't a dupe and is mostly meta commentry.

Comment: @ThomA but what about "I am asking about a specific problem in my regex. However, the other question is solely inquiring about special characters of regexes."?

Comment: @kevinB "I am asking about a specific problem in my regex. However, the other question is solely inquiring about special characters of regexes."?

Comment: if the dupe closer thinks your specific problem is the same as the question they linked to, it's a valid dupe closure.  I have not investigated whether or not that is true, but regardless of whether it is... it doesn't justify your edits.

Comment: A single line that stated *"I reviewed [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions), however, my question is about nquiring about special characters of regexes, but that dicusses* foo *instead."* would have been all you needed then. Then a comment might have explained why "foo" is what you need.

Comment: @KevinB Again, "Hi, so I see that this question has been marked as a duplicate of "What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?". However, in my opinion, this is invalid. Simply because the problem is related to special characters does not mean that the questions are "duplicates". Although the answers may be similar, it stands to reason that the two questions are unique. I am asking about a specific problem in my regex. However, the other question is solely inquiring about special characters of regexes."

Comment: I have read your question. There is no freedom of speech here.

Comment: Your edits state (in way to many words) that you disagree with the duplicate closure. The problem is that it fails to explain __why__. _"This is about a specific problem"_ is not enough, you need to explain why the dupe target does not solve that problem.

Comment: *"I'm talking about the restriction on my freedom of speech"*  [so] and [freedom of speech](https://xkcd.com/1357/) are completely unrelated. [so] isn't the government, and they have no intent of arresting you.

Comment: You don't disagree with the closure? Then what's the problem?

Comment: Personally, I agree with your dispute. it's not a duplicate of *just* that one question given your question has *multiple* problems that needed to be solved. It's your run-of-the-mill debugging question that isn't going to be a long-term useful artifact. but the lock was warranted and the edit was bad.

Comment: "A lock, as done in this case, has effectively ended that rollback war and forced you to take the latter action... so it seems to be doing it's job?"
OK, but what about how he most likely disliked both answers who had nothing to do with our discussion and removed my apologies? I simply apologized to the answer writers for making them lose reputation. Surely there's some abuse there.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with people downvoting answers they think aren't useful.

Comment: @KevinB but objectively, both answers answer my question perfectly well. What's wrong with them? Why dislike them other than trying to harm my post?

Comment: you'd have to ask the downvoter, but i'd assume they're downvoting answers that they feel shouldn't have been posted, for whatever reason. I think that's a poor use of votes, but it's not considered abuse.

Comment: @KevinB And deleting my apologies? Only the moderator could have done that.

Comment: Setting aside the question of whether the answers *deserved* to be downvoted (I'm not an SME, I can't judge that either way), you can't assume that the moderator in question was responsible for that - downvotes are anonymous by design. As for your deleted apologies, comments should only be used to suggest improvements or clarifications to an answer (at least on the main site; there's more leeway on Meta since it's inherently more disscussion-oriented), so the mod was well within their right to delete those.

Comment: and, if the comments included certain keywords, they could have been deleted with a single flag by a not moderator. Sounds like the apology comments (that i can't see) likely included those keywords.

Comment: @KevinB but I didn't swear at them or anything :(

Comment: I'm not aware of what specifically the keywords are, but i think downvote and upvote are both among them.

Comment: Comments are by design temporary and  you should assume they will be deleted. A better way to communicate to other  users is by inviting them to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Consider reviewing [what comments are for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Comments that are not for the correct purpose will likely be deleted. Even comments that are for the correct purpose may be deleted if they are no longer needed.

Comment: Just an FYI: comments can be deleted by the comment author, a moderator, or by having enough flags raised on the comment. The number of flags required varies from 1, if the comment also matches some undisclosed content criteria (determined completely programmatically by the system), up to many flags, if the comment is significantly upvoted. Past needing only one, the most commonly needed number of flags for automatic deletion is 3. I'm not trying to say anything about this situation *other than* just making note that deletion of comments doesn't *require* an elected moderator.

Comment: "Um, no, I simply followed the dupe closure and quoted it to the moderator" - this is a contradiction in terms. The policy **requires you not to** quote policy in questions (or edits to questions), because the questions are supposed to only be questions. Aside from that, the blue shaded box tells you: "If that question doesn’t answer your issue, edit your question **to highlight the difference between the associated question and yours**". You did not do this. Aside from all of that: you are complaining about others being "rude" here; please consider the perceived tone of "Um, no".

Comment: " "I am asking about a specific problem in my regex. However, the other question is solely inquiring about special characters of regexes."?" - So: someone that the site recognizes as knowledgeable on the topic, thought that your question "about a specific problem in my regex" was a duplicate of a question "about special characters of regexes". Did it occur to you, therefore, that the "specific problem in your regex" **might be caused by** "special characters"? If this was not enough information to go off, did you consider using the comments to clarify that?

Comment: "However, in my opinion, this is invalid. Simply because the problem is related to special characters does not mean that the questions are "duplicates"." This is where you went wrong. First off, you started from the position that having your question marked as a duplicate is a bad thing, and without an understanding of what we consider duplicate (or why). Then, instead of saying **why** you think the question **isn't** a duplicate, you shifted the burden of proof, supposing that others should have to explain why it **is**. Then you added several more paragraphs that don't belong in an answer.

Comment: "I simply apologized to the answer writers for making them lose reputation." You did nothing of the sort. Any reputation loss came from the people who downvoted them, who were correctly responding to bad answers (answers added to a duplicate question are **inherently** bad; if they can provide good content that is not already at the duplicate, they should instead be new answers **on the duplicate**).