# Why do moderators close questions?

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions

I have looked through thousands of closed Stack Overflow questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+duplicate%3A0&s=956bce4c-2fb9-4e74-a255-92f9066ad6f6

I don't see why you guys closed any of these questions. Can a moderator please explain to me how you decide if a question should be closed?

I expected this site to be answering my questions after creating a Stack Overflow account. Instead, I just have even more questions about this site and its moderators.

Comment: Each of those closed questions has an explanation at the top.

Comment: @Lukewarm Right at the top it indicates why the question was closed, and clearly indicates that it is not the right place to ask these types of questions. The best site is [meta], but they will probably close it as a duplicate of another post since you are not the first to ask that question since thousands have done it before, so I will give you some links for you to review.

Comment: Side note: Many of those were likely closed by the community, not the mods.

Comment: "I expected this site to be answering my questions after creating a Stack Overflow account" This is the wrong way to look at these sites, it is just asking for frustration. Think of them like a museum, peruse what is here and if you think you have something of value to add "Donate" it. It is not a helpdesk.

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually taken [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of what Stack Overflow is about; it's probably a good idea for you to do so now. Among other things, this would give you a glimpse at why questions are closed and where to find more in-depth information on the site.

Comment: Re *"looked through thousands of ... questions ... I don't see why you guys closed any of these questions"*: Can you provide some examples? Say 10. There are 421,397 questions in the sample (plenty of room for cherry picking). We are not [mind-readers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186035/policy-and-rationale-for-making-close-votes-invisible-to-most-users/186047#186047) (at least I don't think so).

Comment: 2177 upvoted this question so they must've thought it was focused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647069/should-i-use-vagrant-or-docker-for-creating-an-isolated-environment

Comment: 2051 upvoted this question so they must've thought it was focused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack

Comment: 1832 upvoted this question related to programming: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl

Comment: Are you trying to make some kind of point, that these closures are wrong? What you cant see are the millions of closed questions that are deleted.

Comment: they arent just wrong they are "completely missing the dart board" wrong

Comment: Earn the ability to cast a reopen vote and cast one.

Comment: im not even looking that hard for examples, theyre everywhere

Comment: though, i'd suggest at minimum reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Most, if not all, of the closed questions you've linked to fall into the "don't ask about..." list.

Comment: what im trying to say is that the system is rigged so that questions dont get answered, instead i have to deal with rude comments and robotic responses from real people

Comment: that's simply not true. there's been 4,843 answers posted today alone with just a few hundred more questions.

Comment: of those 4,843 answers posted today, how many of them aren't rude comments or passive-aggressive responses

Comment: [All of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A1d). comments weren't part of that search. (that was for yesterday, not today, to be clear.)

Comment: @Lukewarm Sorry, but what exactly is it that you are expecting here going forward? You have already been referred to the rules about on-topic and off-topic criteria. Popularity of question is orthogonal to this; a question can be well-liked and off-topic, or it can be disliked but on-topic, or one of many other combinations. If a question has a score of 2051 but is unfocused, it is still not a good fit for [SO]; it just happened to be tolerated for a while.

Comment: The comments are no longer moving in a productive direction and several have been removed. @Lukewarm if you have more information/considerations than what is currently listed in your question feel free to make a clarifying [edit] as opposed to adding them in the comments.

Answer (score 8):

Moderators close questions for the same reasons that ordinary users close questions.  You can find out why questions are sometimes voted for closure by reading [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance).

If your question is actually "Why do moderators sometimes choose to close questions with a single, binding vote," that's because moderators are not asked to relinquish their ordinary user privileges when they become moderators.  If that doesn't seem fair, consider that moderators are elected by the user community, and are accordingly trusted with the new privileges they are granted.

To put it another way, moderators are encouraged to "be bold," disregard the fact that their vote is binding, and cast it as if they had ordinary user privileges.  In practice, I suspect that moderators are a bit more careful with their close votes, since they're not getting community consensus if they unilaterally vote to close.

But if a post is clearly junk, lock & load.

Answer (score 6):

That's a *lot* of questions.

So in general the reason questions are closed is [due to them being off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) or [unfit for the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

There's also this other thing called "duplicate closure", in which the question *is* on-topic for the site, but was already answered, so instead of duplicating answers, we just close that question and point the OP to the place with answers.  That's not (really) a bad thing.

We don't answer *every* question there is about programming.  If you had that expectation coming into the site, then I'm happy to help reset that expectation with you.