# Question closed since it's opinion-based

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, opinion-based

I'm trying to write a question to get a better understanding of what advantages an [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) cluster provides over a traditional [ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html) system: [When should I use EKS over ECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75567109/when-should-i-use-eks-over-ecs)

However my question got closed since it was an opinionated question (which in my opinion it isn't; it's asking for factual benefits a Kubernetes cluster has over an ECS). How can I reword the question so it doesn't get closed?

Comment: Even if you remove the "opinion" aspects, is that question about programming? Many Kubernetes and related questions get closed as "Not about programming". Looks like it *may* be better suited to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Questions asking for lists of things don’t tend to last very long. Too many possible answers

Comment: Also, you would have to be sure everyone is on the same page as to what constitutes a benefit.

Answer (score 5):

The fundamental purpose of your question is to **make a choice** between two competing options. We more or less don't do that here; the closest we get is comparing multiple *code examples* on an *objective performance metric* (runtime, big-O complexity, memory usage...).

Further, the purpose of the question is to choose between **products and/or services** offered by a third party (Amazon). As explained *in the tag guidance* for [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes), which should have appeared to you *while you were composing the question*:

> KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here. A good rule of thumb is, if it happens outside the pod, it's probably off-topic. If it's about code running inside the pod, it's probably OK.

There is nothing in this question that relates to code.

As a rule of thumb: if you can't *meaningfully* tag your question with the **name of a programming language** (or with something like [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) or [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)); or if you have neither written, nor propose to write, **code that is directly related** to the question, *do not ask it on Stack Overflow*.

If you'd like it from an authoritative source:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance / Not about programming or software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420218)