# My question was closed, what did I miss?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My question, found here:

[What is a simple, fast method to draw triangles to bitmap in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76355752/what-is-a-simple-fast-method-to-draw-triangles-to-bitmap-in-c)

.. was closed. As far as I can tell the close message only says it invites opinion. I don't think this is accurate, I was asking for quite specific code examples. I received one answer to the question; that person appears to have misread or misunderstood what I was trying to achieve. I don't know if they were also the person who closed the question.

At any rate, please look at the question and see if you agree with the reason for closing. If so, I'd like to know what I'm missing. Thank you! If possible I'd like the question to be re-opened.

Comment: I think the biggest issue is the likely the lack of definition of "simple", what is "simple"?

Comment: And similar with the "fast", not to mention the combination of the two... (which might often conflict)

Comment: [This creates a triangle quickly](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/e378b0092c00c7f162a7d4ba7ed6be1e), was simple for me to create, and probably comes nowhere close to answering your question.  What's quick?  What's simple?  These are inherently opinionated questions, and there are tons of possible answers.  Such open-ended questions are really better suited to a [discussion forum](https://www.google.com/search?q=programming+discussion+forum).

Comment: Also the question feels too open ended, you say you prefer to use C# but it would be fine to use C++, you also ask about how to do this with "any SDK". If you don't want to focus on a specific tool it would be best not to mention that "any SDK" part and simply say "How to draw triangles in bitmap with ... in C#?" The part about the libraries / tools you've looked at can go at the end of the question as the research you've already done and what didn't work for you.

Comment: An interesting case. It is more like an unclear question which is a different close reason, but I would agree with comments that there are a few red herring opinions in there which make me lenient to the choice of this being closed as opinionated. It is kind of a quick draw choice for people.

Comment: I appreciate the replies that I've gotten here. I must say however that I am quite diasppointed that people have seen fit to downvote my question all day, tanking my stackoverflow rating, when it was a fair and reasonable question.

Comment: @ErikVerboom The question was not a 'fair and reasonable' question, though. It was too broad, lacking details, sort of asking for tool recommendations, and opinion-based. You can also delete the question and regain your reputation points, if that is your concern. It _is_ unfortunate that Stack Overflow no longer splits out the close reasons that everyone uses to show you exactly what reasons a question was closed under; instead it picks the majority, or if there is an even split (three separate reasons), it picks the reason of the first close voter (moderators or dupe-hammers notwithstanding).

Comment: That being said, it's also unfortunate that your question got 6 pile-on downvotes from the Meta Effect here. A score of -8 for something that isn't spam or rude/abusive content is pretty excessive.

Comment: @TylerH Apparently I'm not allowed to remove my questions and they're still accruing more downvotes. I think this is unfair.

Comment: @ErikVerboom There shouldn't be anything preventing you from deleting the question you linked in this post. It has one answer which is negatively scored and is not accepted. That being said, the question will automatically be deleted by the system in 9 days, at which point you will recover the 20 reputation you have lost due to it.

Comment: @ErikVerboom it works the same for everyone so it is not unfair. Some clever people have used the meta effect to gather some extra upvotes too. It sucks, that's what you meant to say :) It does suck but that does not imply that the process is wrong.

Comment: In some more detail, posting on Meta invites many active curators to review your post; they did, and voted accordingly. While I agree with TylerH that the amount of downvotes is disproportionate, we are admonished to vote on the actual quality of the post, not on our opinion of the author or our sense of pity or sympathy for your plight.

Comment: Be that as it may, I fail to see why asking for help improving a question is in itself a low quality post.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of problems with that question.

It reads much more like a requirements dump then an actual programming problem you have to solve. While we are a code writing service, we like to do so from an  actual problem. That is a missed opportunity because you said:

> But the examples of it that I've found do not show to draw directly to bitmap, instead using a window.

Had you included a working example and explained how that doesn't fit your context we would have had a question with value for future visitors.

The other point is the soliciting for off-site resource. It isn't that clear cut but I can see why people would not think it is very valuable to have a list of answers that point to examples that exist today. There is a reason Stack Overflow has a close reason for it [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417480#417480)

You make the claim

> GDI+ doesn't appear to support those features, so I've excluded that one.

That might be true but it helps if you had backed that up with a source so we could verify / confirm that your conclusion is right. Share you research is preferred. See in the right side bar, step 2: [*You can get better answers when you provide research.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

In your title you use *simple* and *fast*. In your question we're down to *simple*, no mention of *fast* anymore or we must be impressed by *large number of bitmaps*. Simple and fast are imprecise words that don't have meaning without context. When would an answer to your question be acceptable when it comes to simple? Is that defined by the calls needed? The involved structs? Same goes for *fast*. Is 2 triangles per second OK-ish? Or does it need to be 2000 triangles per second? It helps in these cases if you have your benchmarks in the question.

That brings us to how you can try to salvage the question.

- pick one of the examples from OpenTK and adapt it so it is as close to your specs as you can get it
- run benchmarks on your hardware
- include the adapted example code in your question as a [Minimal Reproduceable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- make clear what performance requirement you have
- Ask for how to implement the missing features (for example if you couldn't get the color interpolation working), or
- Ask for how to solve a specific issue (for example: how to get a bitmap from the window), or
- Ask for how to reach a given performance in transactions per second or whatever concrete measurement is applicable

You can state that you're not bound to the given library and/or which alternative architecture you're open for, so answers can venture into alternative libraries or even mixed language solutions within the boundaries of your needed solution.

Once you made those edits to your question make sure to tick the *This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening* so the question goes to the Reopen Queue. Allow for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) to have it re-openend.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. There are definitely some points here that I can resolve.

Comment: The question was intended as "I need to draw triangles and I want a solution that is hardware accelerated and doesn't require unnecessarily complicated code. I would prefer C# but could use C++ if necessary. I have no preference for a particular SDK but I'm not familiar with one that meets my requirements. Could anyone provide one?".
I don't think it makes sense in this scenario to give code examples of things that don't solve my problem, just to show I've done my research. Mostly, I'm just disappointed that I've gotten so many downvotes to a qestion that should be fine to ask.

Comment: @ErikVerboom the hardware acceleration part is maybe the context that makes your question unique as opposed to just "draw me a triangle, fast". On the other hand: hardware accelaration is not something GDI+ will decide, that is up to OS / HAL and driver support of your graphics card. So now your question in a completely different , not necessarily better, ballpark. I still think an example is useful for the odd chance that you missed flipping a  boolean to true in an overload or constructor that makes it automagically HW accelerated.

Comment: @ErikVerboom - you may want to re-read the question - I did not find *any* traces of expectation of a "solution that is hardware accelerated". Note that combined with "from a server-side API" mentioned in the question makes it quite tricky as many server VMs don't even have HW acceleration... (and now you have to compete with AI consuming all GPUs :) )... You really should reconsider your requirements before attempting to repost/update the question.

Comment: Hi Alexei, I wasn't arguing with the feedback. I know I didn't mention 'hardware-accelerated' in the original question. I only added that I think it's problematic that I received a lot of downvotes both on the original question and this one, because the original question was sincere and had, to me, a clear purpose.