# Where can I get advice for the improvement or discuss my closed question?

Tags: discussion

Recently [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76691774/copy-set-windows-format-regional-settings-via-cmd-command-script) has been closed. But according to the closure reason, it's complying with every point of the guidelines (in my opinion). Where can I get a more detailed explanation, and what specific reason(s) is(are) applied for every closure vote? Can I find the people who voted, for asking them by myself?

The reason provided is too broad. In my opinion, as I mentioned above, the question complies with guidelines. Where can I discuss cases like this?

Comment: The close reason is "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." and I agree with it. This is a question about configuring something in an OS, not a programming problem. Sounds much more suitable to SuperUser (but please read their help-center first).

Comment: "The reason provided is too broad." - ??? I don't see that. I see "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.". "Where I can get more detailed explanation, what specific reason(s) is(are) applied for every closure vote?" - does [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476) help?

Comment: @BDL, I disagree with you, because what I need, is a code being suggested for the mentioned configuring. Is the code is not about programming?

Comment: @green: Calling a command in the command line is not programming. If you know which commands to use and you run into a problem with calling these commands or passing data between them, then it might be a coding problem.

Comment: “Can I find people voted for asking them by myself?” - Who voted to close your question is made clear in the history of your question, however, there is no way to contact other users in private (thank goodness for that) nor would it be appropriate. Your question per the help center is out of scope at Stack Overflow

Comment: Take this meta post and the responses to it as a hint that your idea of what Stack Overflow is does not match with reality. You wouldn't be the first where it takes several years before they run into the actual curation part of the site because until then they were asking well-received questions with a fair bit of luck.

Answer (score 13):

The question currently shows up as having been closed as off topic. Screenshots from the Windows UI make the question superficially look like it's simply about using Windows, which would be off topic. If we expect to be able to solve the problem by typing some simple command (or even a few commands), that is still off topic for the same reason - it's a question about how to use your computer and its operating system, not about how to write code or use programmer-specific tools. Try https://superuser.com.

If you saw at any point a message calling the question "too broad", I think it could be the case that e.g. one person voted "needs more focus" and the other two voted "off topic". If we expect that solving the problem requires writing a batch script, in order to *automate* the running of several commands, that is on topic; we have a [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag for that specific reason.

However, a question about batch file scripting needs to be about the actual *scripting*, not just about individual commands. In the same way that we would accept as on-topic a beginner's Python question about how to display text with certain formatting (although it would certainly be a duplicate), but not a question about *what formatting is required* in order to achieve a certain graphical/visual effect.

Furthermore - and this is where "focus" comes into play - it would need to be a *specific* question about some specific *aspect of* the script. In particular:

- a "what's wrong" question would need to be about one specific part of the script that is doing something wrong, with a specific explanation of what is going wrong, which represents where you're at *after* you have done the appropriate debugging necessary to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- a "how do I do this" question needs to be about some specific aspect of the script process itself (e.g. "how do I make it repeatedly use the command until some condition is met / using each of these values?"), not merely about the commands being invoked.

Just like with any other programming language. We don't find the bug for you, and we don't implement the solution for an entire task for you. Instead, we explain the (atomic) issue with what you have already found, or give examples, brief algorithms etc. for individual steps of a process to implement.

Comment: The question shouldn’t be migrated to Super User until it’s significantly improved.

Comment: @SecurityHound agreed; I hope I didn't imply otherwise.

Comment: For the record: Two users voted to migrate to Super User, and one voted "Not suitable for this site → Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more".

Answer (score -7):

It is too broad because from the context of the question you have  not shown that you know enough for us to help you in a reasonable manner with lots of answers or very long answers. It is also mainly based on how the Windows operating system works internally.

The way the question is written (with only images and screen captures) implies you don't have any knowledge of Windows command lines or batch scripts and perhaps manipulating the inner workings of a Windows system. Anyone who attempted to give you a complete answer would have to write you a mini-tutorial on those things, and that is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. We are not your trainers; we are meant to be your peers. You have to move closer to the answer and indicate clearly what part of the solution eludes you. Then we are able to fill that gap.

Have you Internet searched for any part of that answer? What part of which Windows file need changing? Have you started to make a command script? Where on the system will you put the command scripts, and so on.

At the  moment it just looks like you are asking someone for free labour and not help and advice from a colleague.

Make the changes to make it look like less work for anyone and it becomes "not too broad".

Comment: The question asks for the specific commands.  I don't see anything suggesting that it would also require a tutorial on using command prompt and/or writing batch scripts.