# Why was my question closed? (I fixed the issue, and I'm just curious)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, unclear

This is the question: *[Changing Lua code block syntax from source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77030249/changing-lua-code-block-syntax-from-source-code)*

Why was it closed? I fixed the issue, but I revised it to make sense, and it was rejected. I don’t know why.

Comment: I don't know why your Meta post is getting downvoted, but the SO post was downvoted and closed because it's too broad. Modifying the Lua source code unilaterally is not something we can fit in an answer here. Instead try to do it yourself, and if it doesn't work, show us what you tried, what you're expecting, and what happened instead.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. I fixed my issue by myself, but I see your point, there is a lot of things going on in the Lua source code, and it's too much you need to do to get my goal of curly blocks. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: *"bro why am I getting downvoted???!"* Possibly because the question *hasn't* been fixed and that you attempted to *fix* it after it was closed, therefore admitting that you know it was closeworthy prior to posting here meta. This is my thoughts on the post anyway, and therefore I disagree with some of the statements you make here. Also, many users are fans of being called "bro".

Comment: oh ok im confused now.... i was saying I fixed my issue, i got ```{}``` codeblocks working, I was confused why it got closed and now I am even more confused what is going on

Comment: Aren't fans* *(ooops)*

Comment: If something like this were easy enough that *someone else could, in the space of a single Stack Overflow answer, explain to you exactly what to do*... then surely it would *already exist*? Maybe even from the Lua developers directly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here. Let me try to address/list those.

- Stack Overflow is a site to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems. What is missing from your question is *the problem*. If a future visitors wants to learn about altering LUA syntax, what are the keywords, context, search terms they are looking. In the comments you motivation seems to be "because brackets just look way better". That is fine but doesn't really count as a practical coding problem that needs an answer for future visitors.
- On the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77030249/timeline) we can see you got within 4 minutes of posting your first comment that mentioned your question was unclear. Your edit effort should start right there and then. The question got closed a day later and then a day later you made an edit / changed it in focus but didn't really address the other issues. Some useful comments were left both before and after you edited the question. Using those comments to make clarifying edits could have put the question in a better position.
- Seeking help on Meta is a way to improve posts that you feel have value to exist in our knowledge base. As you found out on Main, asking an unclear/broad with a lacking problem description get your question into trouble. Same goes for Meta. We have to guess if you had seen the [guidance in the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and the [supporting Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance) and if you applied, misunderstood or ignored that guidance. Remember that specially on Meta you invite the most experienced users to interact with your posts. We're not here doing just the leg-work for you, you need to show-off on what you researched already. You need to tell us what you need help with.
- Voting is the quality-control mechanism applied by the community on new and existing content. It makes that on Stack Exchange sites you'll find less mis-information, less chit-chat, less non-sense. Voting is a privilege and any "bro" that clicks a voting button helps maintaining the quality of the knowledge base you love and contribute to. Therefor voters need our respect and their signals need to be taken into account. That is better not done with comments that pretend you have not read [What is Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) yet.