# How can we discipline unscrupulous mods?

Tags: discussion

The other day, I spend several hours to explore a certain aspect of Spring Security and post a high-quality self-answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78011773/how-am-i-supposed-to-access-my-endpoints-in-a-no-config-webflux-security-applica). I believe I achieved my goal: the answer is detailed and thorough. In return, both my question and my answer were downvoted, and I had my asking privileges revoked. What's more, the question was closed with a far-fetched reason, it allegedly "needs to be more focused". Even though, the question was very clear and the key parts was even hightlighted in bold, "How do I visit endpoints in a Spring Security app with no explicit config?"

So I wonder, is there any mechanism at all to discipline moderators who abuse their authority? If so, how can I initiate such a process? I realize SO is not a country so it doesn't really have a tiered "court" system, however I hope there's a chance it still provides some ways to appeal and defend yourself against injustice. Thank you

Comment: No mods have interacted with that question, only "normal" users.

Comment: And by what means have you determined that anyone involved with the closure of your question was "unscrupulous"? This would take considerable mind-reading power.

Comment: Instead of this rant you *could* have come to Meta and queried/argued against the closure of the question erm, at question. That is the "court" you are looking for. Instead you came to court and argued the court did not exist and called the judges biased.

Comment: It's very strong assumption that people who interacted with your question were wrong. It takes 3 users to close a question, so that put them in the majority right now.

Comment: The very long answer suggests that the question is more likely too broad. It should probably be more focused.

Comment: Just to answer the titular question: you can raise an abuse of privilege as an issue via moderator flag. If the abuse is by a mod, you should fill out the contact us form. But of course, you must first understand which users are mods. They are the ones with a diamond beside their name.

Comment: I agree that the question is indeed focused, it can be answered somewhat like: "Security was autoconfigured due to being in the classpath and the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation being used, here is how you can authenticate your requests ...". On the other hand I don't really agree with this question, instead of focusing on exacting some punishment, etc. on the closers your focus should be on getting the question reopened.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: indeed. This meta post is focusing on assumed bad intentions when none can *objectively* be shown or could possibly be shown. It's basic premise, that site mods (or truthfully, normal site users with moderation privileges) were purposefully abusing their privileges, cannot be proven. Without someone explicitly stating, "I closed this question because I am unscrupulous", or without objectively demonstrating such behavior with hard data to back this up, this sort of accusation is doomed to go nowhere. And then they ask for punishment without proven guilt. Yikes.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat but if they (mods or not) face no consequences, they are more likely to abuse their power even more, towards other users. It *is* indeed more important to ensure consequences than to just reopen a specific question

Comment: @JoreJoh You might want to check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges on how to handle abusive (site) moderators (but this is not the case here on your question).

Comment: @Dharman can you provide more specific guidelines? What do you mean by "via moderator flag"?

Comment: @JoreJoh mistakes do happen and the site is built to accommodate that, closed questions can be reopened the same way they were closed (by votes). Its best not to assume malice without proper proof for the same. Try applying [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor)

Comment: Flag the post on which the issue occured with the flag type "in need of a moderator attention" and explain how some privilege was abused. Note that mods will decline a request for reopening the question. I am only talking about an actual abuse.

Comment: @Dharman can a user's closing privileges be suspended? What happens if a moderator agrees the question was closed for no good reason?

Comment: Are closing privileges as revokable as asking privileges (or revokable at all)?

Comment: Whoa. I’ve been halfway through the answer and I still don’t see it addressing any of "Is there any way I can interact with a Spring Boot Security application with no explicit configuration and actually visit my endpoints? Or is it in practical terms inaccessible unless I explicitly write some configuration?"  Consider that while this would be a great blog post, it might not be so useful for SO in its current form.

Comment: @JoreJoh Not they cannot. If a user blatantly works against the good of the site, a mod will issue a warning and/or suspension of the account if necessary.

Comment: Also, mods cannot revoke asking privileges or undo the automatic system ban.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's because your didn't read it in full. I described two ways it could be done

Comment: @Dharman even if you don't agree it was unfair in this particular case. Will there be at least a warning if a user closes a question for a far-fetched reason (and you agree)? Or does one have to do that on a systematic basis to actually see any consequences at all?

Comment: @JoreJoh Yeah, that’s kind of what "half way through" means. Mind, I’m not saying it didn’t answer the questions. It just doesn’t look all that useful to someone looking for the actual answer, since it is buried in all the rest. You might want to consider, since it looks like an actual,  objective shortcoming that might be reflected in votes.

Comment: I wouldn't personally have voted to close the question as needing more focus, but there are thousands of active users on this site with many differing opinions who are just trying to curate content. Talking about these folks as "abusing" their privilege or asking how to have them "disciplined" _for having a different opinion to yours_ is at best an over-reaction. I know it is irritating, and sometimes feels unfair, when a question or answer we have written is downvoted, particularly if we personally believe it is high-quality and helpful, but don't blame folks for having different opinions.

Comment: Regarding Hanlon's Razor, it's a double-edged razor. I would often prefer being assumed to be malicious than being assumed to be incompetent.

Comment: @JoreJoh - “Are closing privileges ….?” - Yes; If a community moderator agreed that the closure of a question was harmful to the community, the users who voted to close your question, could be suspended for their actions. However, it’s important to point out, a single downvote against a question absolutely isn’t enough, to cause you to be question banned.  Which means your own history of asking questions is the reason you are question banned. Any question you have asked is considered in your ability to ask new questions. How many deleted questions do you have?

Comment: And note that those other questions contributing to the ban may have been asked in your early days in the community and may have been deleted for years. The server does not care. For good or ill It counts up everything from the beginning of time.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78011773/3) edit to your question wasn’t helpful, nor did it address the reason your question was closed, only thorough community improvement did your questions problems get resolved and make it eligible to be reopened. So before you blame the community, the community, is the only reason it’s not closed.

Comment: It would have to have happened multiple times. A single occurrence can happen accidentally. It doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Dharman how do you know if it's a first occurrence or a one hundredth if you don't keep track?

Comment: @JoreJoh Mods can see all actions taken by the user. If someone says that a user is systematically abusing site's privileges, we will review their past actions and verify.

Comment: @Dharman how can a regular user ever report a "systematic" abuse if they don't have access to that data?

Comment: @JoreJoh A regular user can see public activity and anonymous votes cast on their own questions and answers. For instance, sometimes the serial vote reversal script isn't triggered by suspicious voting patterns, so you can flag for those to be investigated. Of course, this depends on the kind of abuse being reported, if it is in fact abuse. All evidence seen so far in the case of your question is that it was not.

Comment: @E_net4 let's get this straight. You're telling me that I can only expect any consequences for those users if I report a systematic pattern of frivolous clusures. However, I don't have access to the history of those users' actions, including closures, which makes the task impossible. Can you see this inconsistency?

Comment: @JoreJoh I mean, you are not a moderator, so you are not supposed to have full access to other people's actions. But you can observe some patterns in publicly visible activity and raise suspicions through flagging. But again, this incident does not constitute a pattern.

Comment: @E_net4 if user N closed my question, as I believe, unfairly, and I want to check if that incident is part of a larger pattern of frivolous closures (and report a systematic abuse if it's confirmed), what *specific* actions can I take?

Comment: @JoreJoh You do not, at least not without stalking their activity to see other posts closed by them. That information is visible, but not directly searchable. If some user voted to close a single question of yours, then this simply serves no grounds for abuse.

Comment: Sorry that you think that you were wronged, but reflect on what you are calling "unfair" here: three users looked into your question and considered it too broad for the site. Not only that, you were provided an extensive answer below explaining why, so it does not seem to be an isolated opinion either. At this point, it would seem to be more unfair to everyone if you were given an exception, just because you personally don't want it closed.

Comment: @E_net4 you missed my point. We don't *know* if it was the first time they did it. You *assume* is was a single incident. I *assume* it wasn't. To get rid of the assumptions and get it settled, I need to get hold of the data, examine it, and, if my assumption is proved correct, make my case before whatever dispute resolution authority you have. It seems SO makes it impossible thus leaving me defenceless (which, on its own, is yet another act of injustice)

Comment: Back on this whole subject of injustice: 1) this question on Meta attracted attention from curators and moderators alike, so this incident has already been looked into, and the idea that you are completely defenseless in the face of adversity on Stack Overflow is wrong; 2) the question _was_ reopened after you posted this question, so you did get something from this aside from advice. At this point you just seem to want a biased form of "justice" that favors you personally and punishes whoever performed some curation action on your posts. This, frankly, is a bit sick.

Comment: @JoreJoh - You really should assume good faith.  It's one of the major tenants of the Code of Conduct. You seem to believe that there was a major breach of justice. I believe that to be an overstatement, considering the question, was ultimately reopened.

Comment: "We don't know if it was the first time they did it." - Considering that **they did not do anything wrong**, it's hard to see why this is relevant in the current case.

Answer (score 12):

> The other day, I spend several hours to explore a certain aspect of Spring Security and post a high-quality self-answered question.

With respect: you are not the one who gets to judge this.

> I believe I achieved my goal: the answer is detailed and thorough.

**Length does not equal quality.**

It's debatable whether the question requires an MRE for the application at all, since it's clear that the problem manifests with a hello-world app and as such is not caused by the app code per se. At any rate it is *certainly* not necessary to show us almost 70 lines of XML build configuration just to support the assertion "However, I have it in my classpath" - which still doesn't actually explain *what "it" refers to*.

As for the answer, it takes up 11 screens for me. (For comparison, this answer is "only" three and a half screens long, and I wouldn't be surprised if some think that's already excessive, even though I have several separate points to explain.) That's *extraordinarily* long by Stack Overflow standards. Certainly not record-setting, but certainly more than called for. From what I can tell, the *substance* of your Q&A pair is:

Q. I have a simple web app using XYZ system. When I try to make a GET request in the naive way, I get a 401 error that implies an authorization failure. What exactly is implementing the authorization requirement (since it isn't in my code), and how do I make a GET request that includes the credentials in the expected format?

A. The framework automatically instantiates a default authenticator which uses ABC schemes for authentication. Therefore, this is the expected format for the request. Here is some code (or other process) to generate an example request.

**This should not take anywhere near as much vertical screen space** as you have devoted to the topic. In particular, it should not require any exposition of the internals of Spring. All of that is talking *about how you learned* the answer. But Stack Overflow is not about the research you did. **It's about the answer you got**. The reason we expect research is in order to find that answer - not to tell us a story about the research.

If you want to share your enthusiasm for how you discovered something interesting or difficult after doing hours of research, that's what a personal coding blog is for.

Please try to write more concisely.

> In return, both my question and my answer were downvoted, and I had my asking privileges revoked.

The latter is the consequence of an automated system beyond our control. Please read:

[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583)

As for downvotes, they are a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) afforded to everyone with at least 125 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

**Either way, this has nothing to do with moderators.**

> What's more, the question was closed with a far-fetched reason, it allegedly "needs to be more focused". Even though, the question was very clear and the key parts was even hightlighted in bold, "How do I visit endpoints in a Spring Security app with no explicit config?"

First off, **this, too, has nothing to do with moderators**. Everyone with at least 3000 reputation can vote to close questions, and a mere 15 reputation is required to flag posts for consideration by the former group.

The question very definitely [needs more focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/). Focus **does not mean making it visually apparent** where the text of the question is within your post. Focus means taking away irrelevant details, making sure that there is a single question being asked (i.e., that the question couldn't reasonably be split into sub-questions), and making it **self-evident that the question can be answered reasonably briefly**.

If your *own* attempt at answering the question is *that* long, and the question itself includes multiple code blocks, people will naturally conclude that the question can't be answered reasonably briefly.

Keep in mind that, as described in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the experience of reading Stack Overflow is supposed to involve getting an answer promptly and directly; and that Stack Overflow is designed with the expectation that *more than one person will attempt to answer* the question. If you make the question and answer this long, users will have to scroll a long time to see other answers. That's not being considerate of others' time.

As a rule, if you *need* bold highlighting to make it clear what the question actually is, then you have written too much.

> So I wonder, is there any mechanism at all to discipline moderators who abuse their authority? If so, how can I initiate such a process?

What happened here did not involve moderators, did not entail abuse, and only required "authority" under a very generous interpretation of the term.

In the future, if you actually do have a complaint about moderator actions, you can bring it *here*, **but please first read** the relevant FAQ on the general Stack Exchange meta:

[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867)

---

As some general advice for the future:

1. It seems that you understand the general expectation to do research for questions on the main Stack Overflow site. **The same idea applies to Meta**. This is really general, "how to get along with an established, gate-kept community" stuff: when a space documents the basics of its norms openly, you should consider yourself responsible for understanding those basics.
2. In particular, please do not try to level accusations unless you have reasonable confidence regarding whom you're accusing. It looks bad to complain about "mods" when they weren't actually involved.
3. If you have a negative experience, when you go to find out what you can do about it, strongly consider the possibility that you may have been at least partially at fault.
4. If you have a *single* negative experience, when you go to find out what you can do about it, try *not to generalize* without more evidence. Ideally, avoid asking about generalities if you can see any possibility of a resolution that's specific to your situation.

Comment: The site describes self-answered questions as a way to share knowledge. That's what I tried to do: to share knowledge, to educate. Not simply tell readers how to do X. I see SO as an educational platform. A lot of folks do. I invite SO mods and management to recognize it and stop punishing people for that vision

Comment: @JoreJoh Like others before you, you are trying to tell us to shift the vision for Stack Overflow to become something which was simply not designed to be. Granted, knowledge sharing is something which does happen in the platform. However, that does not make it an educational platform. Once you recognize that, you will be much less likely get the feeling of being punished.

Comment: My question and answer are really beside the point. The point is SO doesn't provide any defence mechanisms for users in such cases. If user N closed my question, as I believe, unfairly, and I want to have them see consequences for that (I don't talk death penalty, at least some formal warning), I first have to prove a systematic pattern. When I try to check if that incident is part of a larger pattern of frivolous closures (and report a systematic abuse if it's confirmed), I discover that such information is not available to me. In other words, SO makes it impossible to defend yourself in such

Comment: ......scenarios

Comment: immediately complaining about mods is the act of assuming Stack Overflow is the same as other sites - exactly the best way to completely misunderstand and probably hate the site, because it really is nothing like any other website so it'll only disappoint. There is no "seeing consequences" to other people, we don't do that as regular curators. We only deal with content. If action against a person needs to be taken that will be based on statistics such as flags and votes and it will be performed by people responsible for doing that.

Comment: @JoreJoh you want a formal warning for what could be an honest mistake? Sounds a bit intense here. Especially that people don't seem to agree this is as high quality as you claim...

Comment: "If user N closed my question, as I believe, unfairly, and I want to have them see consequences for that" - **first you must convince others that it was unfair**. This is going to be difficult for you, based on what I have seen so far - because the evidence suggests that you currently a) do not understand the standards for closure and b) are heavily resistant to having those standards explained to you. In fact, to merit "consequences" you should be expected to show more than simply that the closure was unjustified; you'd have to show intent.

Comment: "The site describes self-answered questions as a way to share knowledge. That's what I tried to do: to share knowledge, to educate" - yes, but *within the framework* of a question that is on-topic for the site, and an answer that *just answers the question* rather than giving reams of background context. At any rate, the content should be entirely aimed at *solving practical programming problems*. If you want to talk about the research process, use a personal blog. Stack Overflow is for the conclusions of that research.