I have been banned from asking questions for four days for asking a question that was deemed incorrect
I asked a question about the name of a node.js javascript audio dsp library because I couldn't find it. I was told that the question broke the rules by asking for advice or recommendations. I wasn't looking for recommendations. I deleted the question because I was told it was not allowed and now I face four days of being banned for asking the question and deleting it. This doesn't seem like a very good way to teach people how to use Stack Overflow.

Correct, it is not the best way to teach people, that is why we have a whole help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help , and yes, you were asking for recommendations which is not allowed, you are taking the word "recommendation" literally, it also contains "other off-site resources".

I was trying to find the name of a specific library and was asking for help. How else would I take the word recommendation? I deleted the question because I accepted the fact that it didn't fit the rules. The deletion seemed to have made matters worse.

You can link the question here, else we do not have access since it is deleted.

Perhaps pointing me at the specific part of the help centre rather than treating me like a naughty child might be a better approach. I do not see how coding questions can be answered with no reference whatsoever to "other off-site resources". I will go and read the https://stackoverflow.com/help which will probably take longer than the four days.

Sorry. How do I link the question?

Here you go: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417480#417480

This is the body of the question. I am not having much success trying to find the name of the node.js based audio and DSP library.
I have tried various Google searches but without much success. My apologies in advance for such a relatively stupid question.

May I ask how banning people from asking questions improves their questions?

it protects the site from low quality content, you are past improving questions once you get banned, and this is automatic.

Sorry. I am passed improving questions because I deleted a question I was told specifically was not allowed?

See Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days? for the reasoning behind why temporary question bans exist at all.

We cannot say anything else without looking at the question. Sorry!

I gave you the body of the question.

@cwadeevans The point of the temporary ban is to force you to slow down, because you're close to a full-on question ban. After that, you'll only be able to post one question ever six months. Question bans only happen after multiple closed/low-quality questions, never just a single one. The recommended action is to fix your old questions, rather than deleting them. Deleted questions still count towards the post ban!

Is there some way I can undelete it?

I only asked one question.

The question involved finding the name of a specific library. It didn't seem to be fixable. I deleted because I was told it was not correct. I am being punished for doing what I thought I was being asked.

Since you aren't fully question banned yet, and the one question you did ask isn't really salvageable, just wait out the four days. Take the time to look through the resources on what's on topic, and make sure you make a good question the next time around. You can undelete your question through your profile, assuming it wasn't deleted by a moderator, but it won't get you out of the temporary ban. If the question is truly unfixable, it probably isn't worth undeleting it.

You say that bans only occur after multiple closed or incorrect questions. This is not the case here. As you say "the one question you did ask".

Full-on question bans (where you can only post one question every six months) don't occur after one question, these are what I'm referring to. Usually when we have people complaining about bans, they have a couple of deleted questions under their belt and refuse to admit it, until a mod sets the record straight.

As far as I am aware that is the first question I have asked. I will try and check.

"I was trying to find the name of a specific library and was asking for help." We don't "help" with anything here, as this is not a discussion forum. The point of asking a question is to help build a searchable Q&A that can be of use to others; figuring out something for your own purposes is just an incentive to contribute.

@cwadeevans You might also want to check the similar meta question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

I haven’t asked several poorly received questions. I asked one and I was not warned before submitting this question.

@cwadeevans a question ban is different from being rate limited / warned. What you're looking at is the rate limit / warning that your question isn't well received asking you to wait 4 days before asking your next question. A question ban on the other hand is much more difficult to get out of.

@cwadeevans - So, in 11 years, you have only asked a single question? I trust others have correctly identified that you are rate-limited. Just keep in mind every question you have ever submitted is considered.  So deleting your question instead of improving it only makes has a negative effect on your ability to ask new questions.
